# Showing that $\sqrt5$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt7)$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

How can I prove that $\sqrt5$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt7)$ ?

I can only think of trying to write $\sqrt5 = a+b\sqrt7$ (where $a,b$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$), but I can't think of a good reason that shoes such $a$ and $b$ doesn't exist.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. Do you remember the proof of $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9196/742)

Comment: @AD. of course I do, but I don't see how this helps...

Comment: @Arturo: is there not a closer "duplicate"? I can't recall the specific values (here they are 5,7), but this seems familiar...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, then there exist rationals $a$ and $b$ such that $(a+b\sqrt{7})^2 = 5$. But 
$$(a+b\sqrt{7})^2 = a^2 + 7b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{7} = 5$$
implies $ab=0$ (since $1,\sqrt{7}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, since $7$ is not a square), which implies $5=a^2$ or $5=7b^2$, both of which are impossible with $a$ and $b$ rational.

(In fact, not only are they different, they are not even isomorphic)

More generally, if $p$ and $q$ are distinct squarefree integers different from $1$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})\neq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$, since 
$$(a+b\sqrt{q})^2 = a^2+qb^2 + 2ab\sqrt{q}=p$$
implies $ab=0$, hence $p=a^2$ or $p=qb^2$, and the fact that $p$ is squarefree yields a contradiction.

See also [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9196/742) covering the same ground, or [Bill Dubuque's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) answer to the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9193/742) which shows that for rationals $d$ and $d'$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d'})$ if and only if $d/d'$ is a (rational) square.

Comment: thank you very much, I will accept once those 10 minutes pass.

Comment: @Belgi Note that the proof requires only that $5,7,35$ are not squares of rationals (for the last $5 = 7b^2\:$ $\!\iff\!$ $35 = (7b)^2$). This method works generally - see my answer.

Comment: @Arturo It would be helpful to explicitly state that your inference $ab = 0$ follows from $\sqrt{7}\not\in \mathbb Q$. This allows readers to more easily see the connection between your proof and mine.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $ $ Apply the below lemma (using $\,\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},\sqrt{35}\,$ all $\rm\not\in K = \mathbb Q)$.

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ [K(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}) : K] = 4\ $ if  $\rm\ \sqrt{a},\ \sqrt{b},\ \sqrt{a\:\!b}\ $  all $\rm\not\in K\,$ and $\rm\,\color{#0a0}{2 \ne 0}\,$ in $\rm\,K.$

**Proof** $\ \ $  Let  $\rm\ L = K(\sqrt{b}).\,$ $\rm\,  [L:K] = 2\,$ by  $\rm\,\sqrt{b}  \not\in K,\,$  so it suffices to show $\rm\, [L(\sqrt{a}):L] = 2.\,$ This fails only if  $\rm\,\sqrt{a} \in L = K(\sqrt{b})$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\rm \sqrt{a}^{\phantom{|}} =\  r + s\ \sqrt{b}\ $  for $\rm\ r,s\in K,\,$ which is false, because squaring yields $\rm\,\color{#c00}{[\![1]\!]}\!:\ \ a\ =\ r^2 + b\ s^2 + \color{#0a0}2\,r\,s\,\sqrt{b}^{\phantom{i}}\!,\, $ contra our hypotheses, by below:

$\rm\qquad\qquad rs \ne 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{b}\ \in\  K\ \ $ by solving $\color{#c00}{[\![1]\!]}$ for $\rm\sqrt{b},\,$ using  $\rm\,\color{#0a0}{2 \ne 0}$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\  s = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \ \sqrt{a}\ \in\  K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\  r + s\ \sqrt{b}\ =\ r \in K$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\  r = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{a\:\!b}\in K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\ s\ \sqrt{b},\, \ $times $\rm\,\sqrt{b}.\qquad$ $\bf\small QED$

---

**Generalizations** are in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242), e.g. a proof of the following

**Theorem** $ $ Let $\rm\,Q\,$ be a field with $2 \ne 0,\,$ and $\rm\, L = Q(S)\,$ be an extension of $\rm\,Q\,$ generated by $\rm\,n\,$ square roots  $\rm\,S \!=\! \{ \sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b},\ldots \}$ of $\rm\ a,b,\,\ldots \in  Q.\,$ If all nonempty subsets of $\rm S $ have product $\rm\not\in\! Q\,$ then each successive
adjunction  $\rm\ Q(\sqrt{a}),\  Q(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}),\,\ldots$ doubles  degree over $\rm Q,\,$ so, in total, $\rm\, [L:Q]  = 2^n.\,$  Thus the $\rm 2^n$ subproducts of the product of $\rm\,S\, $ are a basis of $\rm\,L\,$ over $\rm\,Q.$

Comment: Very theoretical. I prefer an high school answer.

Comment: @BobDobbs Again, the OP's tags imply knowledge of ring and field theory, so answers are written assuming knowledge of such. We also have *many* other variants of this question posed at lower level, so there is no need to duplicate such lower-level answers here.

Comment: Simple is better in my opinion But, developing a theory is other thing. I am here for fun  not theory.

Comment: @Bob *Context* is essential. Exercises like this are posed in field theory courses to help illustrate basic field theory ideas. As is often the case - we can eliminate more abstract algebraic notions to obtain more elementary proofs, but doing so obfuscates the key ideas that are essential to learn when mastering field theory. That's why I did not write the above proof in the slightly shorter form by instead squaring $\rm\,\sqrt a-r \,=\, s\sqrt b\, $ (as is common in more elementary contexts) since e.g. doing so slightly obscures the ideas needed for said generalization

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to find a field containing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 7)$ in which $5$ is not a square. The field of $3$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_3$ is such a field, since $7 \equiv1 \mod 3$ and thus $7$ is a square, but $5\equiv 2 \mod 3$ so $5$ is not a square. (For any odd prime $p$, an integer prime to $p$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ if and only if it is a square modulo $p$.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: a nitpick - in the last sentence you mean "an integer *prime to $p$* is a square..."

Comment: Indeed. I've made the change above.