# Prove that $\Bbb Z [\sqrt 2]\ncong \Bbb Z [\sqrt 3].$ ($\cong$ denotes an isomorphic relation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ring-isomorphism

Prove that $\Bbb Z [\sqrt 2]\ncong \Bbb Z [\sqrt 3].$ ($\cong$ denotes an isomorphic relation)

My solution goes like this:

(Here, $I(\phi)$ denotes the kernel of a homomorphism $\phi.$)

We have $$\Bbb Z [\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2:a,b\in \Bbb Z\}$$ and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]=\{a+b\sqrt 3:a,b\in\Bbb Z\}.$

Let $\phi:\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]\to \Bbb Z [\sqrt 3]$ be an isomorphism.

We have, $\phi(1)^2=\phi(1.1)=\phi(1)\implies \phi(1)=1$ or $\phi(1)=0.$

But $\phi(1)=1$ as $\phi$ is onto.

Let $a\in \Bbb Z^+$

We note that, $\phi(a)=a\phi(1)=a.$

Again, let $a\in\Bbb Z^-$

We observe that, $\phi(a)=\phi(-1-1-\cdots-1)=|a|\phi(-1)=-|a|\phi(1)=a\phi(1)=a.$

Thus, $\phi(x)=x, \forall x\in\Bbb Z$ as $\phi(0)=0.$

Therefore, $\phi(a+b\sqrt 2)=a+b\phi(\sqrt 2),\forall a,b\in\Bbb Z.$

Now, $\phi(2)=\phi((\sqrt 2)^2)=\phi(\sqrt 2)^2\implies \phi(\sqrt 2)=\pm\sqrt {\phi(2)}=\pm \sqrt 2.$

Let $\phi(\sqrt 2)=-\sqrt 2$ then, $$\phi(a+\sqrt 2b)=a-\sqrt 2b\implies \phi(\sqrt 2)=\phi(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2.0)=\sqrt 2, $$ a contradiction.

Thus, $\phi(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 2$ and so, $\phi(a+b\sqrt 2)=a+b\sqrt 2.$

But then, $\phi$ is not onto.

For if, $ a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\phi(a+b\sqrt 2)=a+b\sqrt 2=1-\sqrt 3$ then, $a$ and $b$ have no solution in $\Bbb Z.$

So, $\phi$ cannot be an isomorphism. This means $\Bbb Z [\sqrt 2]\ncong \Bbb Z [\sqrt 3].$

---

I feep the part where I wrote,

> For if, $ a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\phi(a+b\sqrt 2)=a+b\sqrt 2=1-\sqrt 3$ then, $a$ and $b$ have no solution in $\Bbb Z$

needs a little bit more justification. I can't find a way to rigorously show that indeed, no solution of $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ exists.
Is there any way to preswnt this statement in a more justified way? Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Lastly, if there is something wrong with my solution, please do point it out.

Comment: try to square the expression and see if you get a contradiction

Comment: @SineoftheTime Squaring the expression gives us, $a^2+2b^2+2\sqrt ab=1+3-2\sqrt 3=4-2\sqrt 3.$ But I don't notice any contradictions.

Comment: The two rings both have the integer $1$ as the multiplication identity. In the first ring, exists $x$ s.t. $x^2=2\cdot 1$, while the second does not.

Comment: $3$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z [\sqrt 2]$ but not in $\Bbb Z [\sqrt 3]$.

Comment: You overcomplicate it. It is sufficient to show that there is no element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ whose square is equal to $2$. If you know how a general element in this ring looks like, then it should be easy.

Comment: For $\,a,b,c\in\Bbb Q\!:\ a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3 = 0 \Rightarrow a,b,c=0\,$ follows immediately from the well-known facts that the square roots of $\:\!2,\:\!3\:\!$ *and* $\:\!2\cdot 3\:\!$ are all irrational, see the [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/125639/242) in the linked dupe. The common direct proofs are special cases of the proof of that Lemma  - which is the key idea (inductive step) needed to generalize the above implication to any number of square roots.

Comment: Your argument that $\phi(\sqrt{2})\ne -\sqrt{2}$ is wrong.

Comment: @AllenBell But why?

Comment: @Thomas Finley You let $a=\sqrt{2}$, but $a$ has to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment, you can try to square both sides to see if you arrive to a contradiction:
$$a+b\sqrt 2=1-\sqrt 3\implies b\sqrt2+\sqrt3=1-a\implies2b^2+3+2b\sqrt6=1-2a+a^2$$
Now rewrite the expression as follows $2b\sqrt6=-2-2b^2-2a+a^2$, and consider two different cases: $2b\neq 0$ and $2b=0$.

Comment: If $2b=0$ then $b=0$ and we have, $a^2-2a-2=0\implies (a-1)^2=3\implies a=1\pm\sqrt 3,$ a contradiction as, $a\in\Bbb Z.$ So, $2b\neq 0$. But what after that?

Comment: @ThomasFinley if $2b\neq 0$, you can divide and then you get $\sqrt6=\frac mn$ where $m,n \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Ah, right then this is again a contradiction as $\sqrt 6$ is irrational. So, $2b\neq 0$ is false as well and this is absurd and so again, we get a contradiction. So, we have no pre-image of $1-\sqrt 3$ under $\phi$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @ThomasFinley that's correct, basically if $2b\neq0$ or $2b=0$ you have always a contradiction

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque why is it a duplicate? It's a solution verification question

Comment: Because the sought "little bit more justification" is already in the linked dupe (and *many* other answers).

Answer (score 2):

Hint : If we assume that there exists an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 3]$ and call this map $\phi $ as you did. Then there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(\sqrt2)=x+y\sqrt3$. 2 is a square in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$, so it must also be a square in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt3$. But then we have : $$2=\phi(2)=\phi(\sqrt2^2)=\phi(\sqrt2)^2=(x+y\sqrt3)^2=(x^2+3y^2)+2xy\sqrt3$$

What are the possible solutions of x and y?

Comment: @ThomasFinley exactly, in other words this equation has no integer solutions and we are done.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).