# Comparing two quadratic number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\;$$K = \Bbb Q$[$\sqrt{-5}$] $\;$and let$\;$ $L = \Bbb Q$[$\sqrt{-6}$]$\,$. While it is clear that, as fields, K and L are distinct, if each arithmetic operation is considered separately, they seem to share a number of common features.  For example, on the additive side, K and L are isomorphic since each is just a two dimensional vector space over the rationals.  On the multiplicative side, their respective rings of integers share the same trivial unit group (w = 2) and the same nontrivial class group (h = 2).  Can one say more?

Question:  Are the multiplicative groups of K and L isomorphic?

Thanks.

Comment: Well they're not isomorphic as fields.  And their number rings have different irreducibles.

Comment: Purely group-theoretically $K^*/\{\pm1\}$ and $L^*/\{\pm1\}$ are torsion-free abelian groups of countable rank without divisible elements. Does this make them free $\Bbb Z$-modules of the same rank?

Comment: @Lubin, the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbf{Z}$ is torsion-free of countable rank without divisible elements, but is not free.

Comment: And, @Epargyreus, the direct product of countably many copies of $\Bbb Z$ is not of countable rank.

Comment: @Lubin, yes, my mistake. Your question probably does have a positive answer, although in this case I think my answer below is possibly more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

No, the quadratic number fields are not isomorphic, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/is-mathbbq-sqrt2-cong-mathbbq-sqrt3) for several proofs concerning possible isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d'})$. Moreover their discriminant and the  Minkowski bound of their rings of integers is different. For $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ it is $\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{20}$, and for $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ it is $\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{24}$. Still, the class number is $2$ in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The similarities between the two cases are probably best expressed in binary quadratic forms with integer coefficients and variable values. The statements about primes are in Cox, *Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$* The shorthand "good, bad, medium" was taught to me for use in writing programs, by Irving Kaplansky. Turns out there is a [second edition (2013) of COX.](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html)

The form $x^2 + 5 y^2$ integrally represents $5$ and all primes $p \equiv 1,9 \pmod {20}.$ Call these the "good" primes. The form $2x^2 + 2xy + 3 y^2$ integrally represents $2$ and all primes $p \equiv 3,7 \pmod {20}.$ Call these the "medium" primes. The "bad" primes are all $q \equiv 11,13,17,19 \pmod {20}.$

A positive integer $n$ is integrally represented by $x^2 + 5 y^2$ if and only if, in factoring $n,$ the exponent of each bad prime is even, and the sum of all the exponents of medium primes is even.

The form $x^2 + 6 y^2$ integrally represents  all primes $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod {24}.$ Call these the "good" primes. The form $2x^2  + 3 y^2$ integrally represents $2,3$ and all primes $p \equiv 5,11 \pmod {24}.$ Call these the "medium" primes. The "bad" primes are all $q \equiv 13,17,19,23 \pmod {20}.$

A positive integer $n$ is integrally represented by $x^2 + 6 y^2$ if and only if, in factoring $n,$ the exponent of each bad prime is even, and the sum of all the exponents of medium primes is even.

There is a resemblance at the level of represented numbers. Each genus has only one class, and each discriminant has just two genera.

Answer (score 1):

The question is "are the multiplicative groups $K^{\times}$ and $L^{\times}$ isomorphic? The answer is yes, but this is fairly weak result.  Let $\mu_K$ be the subgroup of roots of unity of $K^{\times}$.

**Lemma** Let $K$ be a number field. Then $K^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum $\Gamma$ of $\mu_K$ and countably many copies of $\mathbf{Z}$.

**Proof** This is the idea. Suppose that  the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ had class number one. Then every element of $K^{\times}$ could be factored uniquely into a product of a unit and powers (possibly negative) of irreducible elements. Choosing a basis for the unit group (which is isomorphic to the direct sum of $\mu_K$ and a finitely many copies of $\mathbf{Z}$) and choosing an irreducible element for each prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$ gives the desired isomorphism of $K^{\times}$ to 
$$\Gamma = \mu_K \oplus \bigoplus_{\mathbf{N}}\mathbf{Z}.$$

In general, the ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ will not have unique factorization, but that is easily fixed -- the ring $\mathcal{O}_K[1/S]$ *will* have unique factorization for some (many) choices of integer $S$, and the unique group $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_K[1/S]$ will be finitely generated, and so the same argument applies.