# Prove that $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Suppose there exists an isomorphism
$\Phi \colon \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. Then, of course, it must be the case that $\Phi(1) = 1$. Hence
\begin{align*}
2
&= 1+1
= \Phi(1) + \Phi(1)
= \Phi(1 + 1) \\
&= \Phi(2)
= \Phi(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2})
= \Phi(\sqrt{2}) \Phi(\sqrt{2})
= \Phi(\sqrt{2})^2.
\end{align*}
In other words, $\Phi(\sqrt{2}) = \pm\sqrt{2}$. I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Just for future reference, [formatting tips here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/is-mathbbq-sqrt2-cong-mathbbq-sqrt3)

Answer (score 4):

If $(a+b\sqrt3)^2=2$, then  $$a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt3=2, $$ so $a^2+3b^2=2$ and $2ab=0$. You have either $a=0$ or $b=0$, giving $3b^2=2$ or $a^2=2$, both impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $ p =a + b\sqrt{3}$ (with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$), which is a general element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$,  is such that $p^2 = 2$.

And $p^2 = (a^2 + 3b^2) + 2ab\sqrt{3} = 2$. So $2ab = 0$ and $a^2 + 3b^2 = 2$, hence...

Answer (score 0):

**An other way.** Suppose $\sqrt 2\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$, then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)=K$.  Let $\sqrt 2=a+b\sqrt 3$ with $a,b\in \mathbb Q$. You have that $$[\times \sqrt 3]=\begin{pmatrix}0&3\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ refer to the basis $\{1,\sqrt 3\}$ and $$[\times \sqrt 2]=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
refer to the basis $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$.

Therefore,
$$0=\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\sqrt 2)=a\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\sqrt 3)+2b\implies 2b=0\implies b=0$$
and thus $$\sqrt 2 =a\sqrt 3\implies a=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}\in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$$
which is a contradiction.