# A false proof $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I read the proof that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$ and it makes since.  However I cannot understand what is wrong with the following map $\varphi$.

$$
\varphi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) \to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)
$$
defined by
$$
\varphi(a+b\sqrt2)\mapsto a+b\sqrt3.
$$
and this is a 1-1 map and has the properties
$$
\varphi(a+b)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b) \\
\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)
$$
My error will be appreciated.

Comment: $\varphi(\sqrt{2}^2)=\varphi(2)=2$ or $\varphi(\sqrt{2}^2)=\varphi(\sqrt{2})^2=\sqrt{3}^2=3$.

Comment: You say it has the property $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$, but it doesn't - that's the problem.

Comment: They are isomorphic _as vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$_, but not as fields.

Comment: For further insight see the prior question: [Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})?$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9188/242)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$2=\varphi(2)=\varphi(\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2)=\varphi(\sqrt2)\varphi(\sqrt2)=\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt3=3$$

Comment: must i test more things then just homomorphism and 1-1?

Comment: @DanielHouston: Asaf's point is that _it is not a homomorphism_: it fails to satisfy $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ when $a=b=\sqrt2$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I understand now thank you.

Comment: @Daniel: You should continue checking that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism only if you agree that $2=3$, in which case, since $0=1$, many more things can be proved. The point is that your homomorphism might be additive, but not multiplicative.

Answer (score 5):

The map $\varphi$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space isomorphism, but not a ring homomorphism.

Under a ring isoomorphism, corresponding elements should have the same minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ don't. So, not only $\varphi$ is not a ring homomorphism, but there can be *no* isomorphism, because no element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has $X^2-3$ as its minimal polynomial.