# Dimension of R over Q

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a quick proof as to why the vector space of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbbq)

consider R as a vector space over Q then what is the dimension and how do we prove it

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbbq

Comment: If you're asking specifically what which infinite cardinal number, i.e., the dimension of a basis, then the answers at the duplicate don't directly answer your question.  However, you can extend the ideas in Arturo's answer there to see that the dimension is $2^{\aleph_0}$, as Pete L. Clark commented on Gadi A.'s answer below.  You could also see this by witnessing a linearly independent set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, as I commented with link on Arturo's answer to the other question.

Answer (score 5):

The dimension is infinite; it suffices to show that the powers of, say, $\pi$ are linearly independent (a nontrivial finite linear combinations of powers of $\pi$ that equals 0 would show $\pi$ to be an algebraic number, which it is not).

Comment: The dimension of a vector space over a field is a cardinal number.  "Infinite" or "infinity" is not a cardinal number.  The answer here is that the dimension is $c = 2^{\aleph_0}$.