# The square roots of different primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, field-theory

> I need to find a way of proving that the square roots of a finite set 
>   of different primes are linearly independent over the field of 
>   rationals.

I've tried to solve the problem using elementary algebra 
and also using the theory of field extensions, without success. To 
prove linear independence of two primes is easy but then my problems 
arise. I would be very thankful for an answer to this question.

Comment: I need the square roots of prime numbers

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51638.html

Comment: Also, see this: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/

Comment: This also comes up in T..'s answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbbq/6517#6517

Comment: @J.M.: after Yuval's hint to the mathforum I'd like to mention, that the text of the question is 100% identical with that of the mathforum of 1996, and the fact that neither its reference was given nor anything about the existing answers there was mentioned I assume a) this is not a real question (also there was no followup interaction of "user8465") , and (see the recent meta thread on spam) b) maybe not even a real person asking but possibly an automated transfer of a somehow mathematically sounding text. Maybe that method of spam has been refined recently...

Comment: add: the meta-thread on spambots which I mentioned in the previous comment is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063

Comment: @Gottfried The question is surely not spam - see my comments [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/whats-up-with-all-the-spambots/3072#3072)

Comment: A recent post on MO which is related: [Sum of square roots of natural numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/396205).

Answer (score 157):

Below is a simple proof from one of my old sci.math posts, followed by reviews of related papers.

**Theorem** $ $ Let $\rm\,Q\,$ be a field with $2 \ne 0,\,$ and $\rm\, L = Q(S)\,$ be an extension of $\rm\,Q\,$ generated by $\rm\,n\,$ square roots  $\rm\,S \!=\! \{ \sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b},\ldots \}$ of $\rm\ a,b,\,\ldots \in  Q.\,$ If all nonempty subsets of $\rm S $ have product $\rm\not\in\! Q\,$ then each successive
adjunction  $\rm\ Q(\sqrt{a}),\  Q(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}),\,\ldots$ doubles  degree over $\rm Q,\,$ so, in total, $\rm\, [L:Q]  = 2^n.\,$  Thus the $\rm 2^n$ subproducts of the product of $\rm\,S\, $ are a basis of $\rm\,L\,$ over $\rm\,Q.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on the tower height $\rm\,n =$ number of root adjunctions. The Lemma below implies $\rm\ [1, \sqrt{a}\,]\ [1, \sqrt{b}\,] = [1, \sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}, \sqrt{ab}\,]\ $  is a $\rm\,Q$-vector space basis of $\rm\, Q(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})\,$ iff $\:\!1\:\!$ is the only basis element in $\rm\,Q.\,$
We lift it to $\rm\,  n > 2\,$ i.e. $\, [1, \sqrt{a_1}\,]\ [1, \sqrt{a_2}\,]\cdots [1, \sqrt{a_n}\,]\,$ with $2^n$ elts.

$\rm n = 1\!:\ L = Q(\sqrt{a})\ $  so  $\rm\,[L:Q] = 2,\,$   since $\rm\,\sqrt{a}\not\in Q\,$ by hypothesis.

$\rm n > 1\!:\ L = K(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}),\,\ K\ $  of height  $\rm\,n\!-\!2.\,$  By induction   $\rm\,[K:Q]  =  2^{n-2} $ so we need only show: $\rm\  [L:K] = 4,\,$ since then  $\rm\,[L:Q] = [L:K]\ [K:Q] = 4\cdot 2^{n-2}\! = 2^n.\,$ The lemma below shows $\rm\,[L:K] = 4\,$  if  $\rm\ r = \sqrt{a},\ \sqrt{b},\ \sqrt{a\,b}\ $  all $\rm\not\in K,\,$
true by induction on  $\rm\,K(r)\,$ of height $\rm\,n\!-\!1\,$ shows $\rm\,[K(r):K] = 2\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,r\not\in K.\ \ $  $\bf\small QED$

---

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ [K(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}) : K] = 4\ $ if  $\rm\ \sqrt{a},\ \sqrt{b},\ \sqrt{a\,b}\ $  all $\rm\not\in K\,$ and $\rm\, 2 \ne 0\,$ in $\rm\,K.$

**Proof** $\ \ $  Let  $\rm\ L = K(\sqrt{b}).\,$ $\rm\,  [L:K] = 2\,$ by  $\rm\,\sqrt{b}  \not\in K,\,$  so it suffices to show $\rm\, [L(\sqrt{a}):L] = 2.\,$ This fails only if  $\rm\,\sqrt{a} \in L = K(\sqrt{b})$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\rm \sqrt{a}\ =\  r + s\ \sqrt{b}\ $  for $\rm\ r,s\in K,\,$ which is false, because squaring yields $\rm\,\color{#c00}{(1)}:\ \ a\ =\ r^2 + b\ s^2 + 2\,r\,s\  \sqrt{b},\, $ which is contra to hypotheses as follows:

$\rm\qquad\qquad rs \ne 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{b}\ \in\  K\ \ $ by solving $\color{#c00}{(1)}$ for $\rm\sqrt{b},\,$ using  $\rm\,2 \ne 0$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\  s = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \ \sqrt{a}\ \in\  K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\  r + s\ \sqrt{b}\ =\ r \in K$

$\rm\qquad\qquad\  r = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{a\,b}\in K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\ s\ \sqrt{b},\, \ $times $\rm\,\sqrt{b}.\qquad$ $\bf\small QED$

In the classical case $\rm\:Q\:$ is the field of rationals and the square roots have radicands being distinct primes. Here it is quite familiar that a product of any nonempty subset of them is irrational [since,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1104334/242) over a UFD,
a product of coprime elements is a square iff each factor is a square
(mod unit multiples). Hence the classical case satisfies the theorem's hypotheses.

Elementary proofs like that above are often credited to Besicovitch
(see below). But I have not seen his paper so I cannot say for sure
whether or not Besicovic's proof is essentially the same as above.
Finally, see the papers reviewed below for some stronger results.

---

2,33f  10.0X
Besicovitch, A. S.
On the linear independence of fractional powers of integers.
J. London Math. Soc. 15 (1940). 3-6.

Let  $\ a_i = b_i\ p_i,\ i=1,\ldots s\:,\:$ where the  $p_i$  are  $s$  different primes and
the  $b_i$  positive integers not divisible by any of them. The author proves
by an inductive argument that, if  $x_j$  are positive real roots of
$x^{n_j} - a_j = 0,\  j=1,...,s ,$ and  $P(x_1,...,x_s)$  is a polynomial with
rational coefficients and of degree not greater than  $n_j - 1$  with respect
to  $x_j,$ then  $P(x_1,...,x_s)$  can vanish only if all its coefficients vanish. $\quad$ Reviewed by W. Feller.

---

15,404e  10.0X
Mordell, L. J.
On the linear independence of algebraic numbers.
Pacific J. Math. 3 (1953). 625-630.

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and  $x_1,\ldots,x_s$  roots of the equations
$\ x_i^{n_i} = a_i\ (i=1,2,...,s)$ and suppose that (1) $K$ and all $x_i$ are real, or
(2) $K$ includes all the $n_i$ th roots of unity, i.e. $ K(x_i)$ is a Kummer field.
The following theorem is proved. A polynomial $P(x_1,...,x_s)$ with coefficients
in $K$ and of degrees in $x_i$, less than $n_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots s$, can vanish only if
all its coefficients vanish, provided that the algebraic number field $K$ is such
that there exists no relation of the form  $\ x_1^{m_1}\ x_2^{m_2}\:\cdots\: x_s^{m_s} = a$, where $a$ is a number in $K$ unless  $\ m_i \equiv 0 \mod n_i\ (i=1,2,...,s)$. When $K$ is of the second type, the theorem was proved earlier by Hasse [Klassenkorpertheorie,
Marburg, 1933, pp. 187--195] by help of Galois groups. When $K$ is of the first
type and $K$ also the rational number field and the $a_i$ integers, the theorem was proved by Besicovitch in an elementary way. The author here uses a proof analogous to that used by Besicovitch [J. London Math. Soc. 15b, 3--6 (1940) these Rev. 2, 33].  $\quad$  Reviewed by H. Bergstrom.

---

46 #1760  12A99
Siegel, Carl Ludwig
Algebraische Abhaengigkeit von Wurzeln. (German)
Acta Arith. 21 (1972), 59-64.

Two nonzero real numbers are said to be equivalent with respect to a real
field  $R$  if their ratio belongs to  $R$. Each real number  $r \ne 0$  determines
a class  $[r]$  under this equivalence relation, and these classes form a
multiplicative abelian group  $G$  with identity element $[1]$. If  $r_1,\dots,r_h$
are nonzero real numbers such that $r_i^{n_i}\in R$ for some positive integers $n_i\  
(i=1,...,h)$, denote by $G(r_1,...,r_h) = G_h$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by
$[r_1],\dots,[r_h]$ and by $R(r_1,...,r_h) = R_h$ the algebraic extension field of
$R = R_0$ obtained by the adjunction of $r_1,...,r_h$. The central problem
considered in this paper is to determine the degree and find a basis of $R_h$
over $R$. Special cases of this problem have been considered earlier by A. S.
Besicovitch [J. London Math. Soc. 15 (1940), 3-6; MR 2, 33] and by L. J.
Mordell [Pacific J. Math. 3 (1953), 625-630; MR 15, 404]. The principal
result of this paper is the following theorem: the degree of $R_h$ with respect
to $R_{h-1}$ is equal to the index $j$ of $G_{h-1}$ in $G_h$, and the powers $r_i^t\ 
(t=0,1,...,j-1)$ form a basis of $R_h$ over $R_{h-1}$. Several interesting
applications and examples of this result are discussed. $\quad$ Reviewed by H. S. Butts

Comment: This is top-notch!

Comment: @BillDubuque: Yes, a truly excellent posting!

Comment: Thanks! I just came across this theorem in an article related to rigidity of matrices and was at wits end how to prove it, until  Qiaochu Yuan gave me a link to this post.

Comment: I don't understand a small part in the proof, can you please explain it ? a.what is the meaning of the notation $[1,\sqrt(a)][1,\sqrt(b)]$ ? b. I got to "true by induction on $K(r)$", I don't understand the use of the induction hypothesis (I understand it sais $[K:Q]=2^{n-2}$, but thats all I get from the induction hypothesis...).

Comment: @BillDubuque: I read this couple more times and given it some thouht, I agree that $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}$ are not in $K$ by the hypothesis that the degree of the tower with hight $n-1$ is $2^{n-1}$ but I can't figure why $\sqrt{ab}$ is not in $K$ (it is not clear by the induction hypothesis since $\sqrt{ab}$ is not adjoined in any step...). I would be greatfull if you can explain this part of the proof, it is very interesting!

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding well the phrase "If every nonempty subset of S has product $\not\in\Bbb Q$" but if you consider $\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10}$ and $\sqrt{15}$, then neither of them nor their products are in $\Bbb Q$ (rational numbers), but $2\sqrt{15}=\sqrt{6}\sqrt{10},$ so $\sqrt{15}$ is in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$ and this contradicts the thesis of the Theorem.

Comment: @Andres There is no problem since $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{10}\sqrt{15} = \sqrt{900} = 30\in\Bbb Q,\:$ so the Theorem does not apply.

Comment: As always, your mathematics is excellent and your typesetting is atrocious. :)

Comment: @Potato fyi: 4 years ago MathJax had *many* bugs. Tthe typesetting was done by macros composed to workaround these problems,

Comment: In the above comment you mentioned that $[K(r):K]=2$. That's because by induction hypothesis $K(r)$ has height $n-1$ and $[K(r):K]$ is equal to $\dfrac{[K(r):Q]}{[K:Q]}=2^{n-1}/2^{n-2}=2$. Right?

Comment: @KFR Yes, that's correct.

Comment: what is$ [1,\sqrt{a}]$?

Comment: @eraldcoil A basis of $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt a)\,$ over $\,\Bbb Q\ \ $

Comment: @Belgi After thinking about this proof some, I think that this point reveals a flaw in the argument. Namely: Bill's proof requires us to show that for all $n\geq 2$, for any $n$ pairwise distinct primes $p_i$ we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \dots , \sqrt{p_{n-2}}, \sqrt{p_{n-1}p_n})]=2$. That is how we conclude $\sqrt{p_{n-1}p_n} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$. But to prove that is essentially to prove the original statement. But I hope I am wrong and someone corrects me.

Comment: I made a typo in my above comment. That extension should be OVER $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \dots , \sqrt{p_{n-2}})$.

Comment: @Matthew No, for the OP case the hypothesis is that products of square-roots of distinct primes are not rational (i.e. they are multiplicatively independent over $\Bbb Q).\,$ This is easy, e.g. by [classical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441234/242) that $\,\sqrt n\,$ is irrational if some prime occurs to odd power in $\,n$.  To better understand how the proof works I recommend that you write the inductive steps in greater detail.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see now. My mistake was that I was trying to specialize the inductive hypothesis to solely collections of square roots of distinct primes, hoping this would suffice to show square roots of distinct primes were independent. But to get that conclusion, more generality is necessary. (Namely, in $\mathbb{Q}$, I think one needs to work at least with collections of pairwise coprime integers $>1$. As you say, it is easy in the base case. And with this general hypothesis, $[K(\sqrt{p_{n-1}p_n}): Q] = 2$ falls out no differently than as it did for $\sqrt{p_{n-1}}, \sqrt{p_n}$.)

Answer (score 40):

Assume that there was some linear dependence relation of the form

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \sqrt{p_k} + c_0 = 0 $$

where $ c_k \in \mathbb{Q} $ and the $ p_k $ are distinct prime numbers. Let $ L $ be the smallest extension of $ \mathbb{Q} $ containing all of the $ \sqrt{p_k} $. We argue using the field trace $ T =  T_{L/\mathbb{Q}} $. First, note that if $ d \in \mathbb{N} $ is not a perfect square, we have that $ T(\sqrt{d}) = 0 $. This is because $ L/\mathbb{Q} $ is Galois, and $ \sqrt{d} $ cannot be a fixed point of the action of the Galois group as it is not rational. This means that half of the Galois group maps it to its other conjugate $ -\sqrt{d} $, and therefore the sum of all conjugates cancel out. Furthermore, note that we have $ T(q) = 0 $ iff $ q = 0 $ for rational $ q $.

Taking traces on both sides we immediately find that $ c_0 = 0 $. Let $ 1 \leq j \leq n $ and multiply both sides by $ \sqrt{p_j} $ to get

$$ c_j p_j + \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n, k\neq j} c_k \sqrt{p_k p_j} = 0$$

Now, taking traces annihilates the second term entirely and we are left with $ T(c_j p_j) = 0 $, which implies $ c_j = 0 $. Since $ j $ was arbitrary, we conclude that all coefficients are zero, proving linear independence.

Comment: That is such a cool proof. I was just wondering how you know that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galios. Even if it is not Galios, does taking its normal closure do the trick since that would still be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ so its fixed field will be the rationals?

Comment: It does do the trick, yes; however we already know that $ L/\mathbb Q $ is  Galois since it is the splitting field of $ \prod_{p_k} (X^2 - p_k) $ over $ \mathbb Q $.

Comment: I see, thank you. I thought that it had to be irreducible, but a simple Googling disabused me of that.
Once again, that was cool.

Comment: Pretty! It just feels like magic. Can you give intuition to how you came up with it (I know it was long ago). In general I love your questions and answers and would love to ask your opinion on how to approach some things in algebra if you're available.

Comment: This is a nice argument (which I upvoted long time ago) : even if we don't know the degree of $L/\Bbb Q$, we know that for $d=p_ip_j$ ($i \neq j$), the subgroup $Gal(L / \Bbb Q(\sqrt d))$ has index $2$ in $Gal(L/\Bbb Q)$, so that the $L/\Bbb Q$-trace of $\sqrt d$ must vanish.

Comment: Let me mention another proof that uses algebraic number theory, briefly mentioned in the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657374) : if $n_i$ are square-free integers and $n$ is a square-free integer having an odd prime factor $p \nmid n_1 \cdots n_r$, then we have 
$$\sqrt n \not\in L:=\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{n_1}, ..., \sqrt{n_r}\right).$$

Comment: Indeed, the set of ramified primes in the compositum $L$ is the union of the ramified primes in each $\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{n_i}\right)$. If we had $\sqrt n \in L$, then the prime $p$ would be ramified in $L$ (since it ramifies in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt n)$). But the only odd primes ramifying in $L$ are the prime divisors of the $n_i$, and $p$ is not among them by assumption. Whence the claim!

Answer (score 38):

Iurie Boreico presents several Olympiad-style proofs of this fact in the [Harvard College Mathematics Review](http://www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf). I give a somewhat more sophisticated proof [in this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/).

The source of the sophistication is interesting. For any particular finite set of primes, there is a completely elementary proof which is found by finding a suitable prime witness $q$ relative to which all but one of the primes is a quadratic residue. But in the above I use quadratic reciprocity and Dirichlet's theorem to show that $q$ always exists in general. (I am actually not sure if Dirichlet's theorem is necessary here.)

Comment: The first link seems to be broken now. Can anyone provide a copy of it?

Comment: @Leullame, the paper can be found [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf) (the full issue, not just the individual paper).

Comment: Currently here: http://abel.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf, page 87.