# Showing field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}$ degree 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, field-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The square roots of the primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-rationa)

I am trying to classify the Galois group of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}$ and am getting stuck on trying to show that the extension is degree 8. I understand that you can look at intermediate fields in the tower to get

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})}][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$

and each of these has degree 2. But is there an easy way to show $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})] = 2$? I tried showing that $\sqrt{5}$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}\}$ but it's a long mess, and I'm wondering if there's a more clever way to do this.

More generally, is it true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, ..., \sqrt{p_n})/\mathbb{Q}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes has degree $2^n$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was already asked some time ago.

Comment: @Adrian: You might be thinking of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-rationa

Comment: @Arturo Yes, that's the one that I was thinking about.

Comment: @Arturo: the question is very similar, but technically asks for a slightly weaker claim...

Comment: @Qiaochu: The *second* part of the post amounts to the same as that question, doesn't it? If the extension had degree stricly smaller than $2^n$ then there would be a linear dependence between the roots.

Comment: @Arturo: well, in any case I suppose Bill Dubuque's answer and the article of Iurie Boreico's that I linked to answers this question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it makes for good reading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An easy way to show that $\sqrt{5}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is to note that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\colon\mathbb{Q}]=4$, so by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory it has either one or three intermediate fields of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since a group of order $4$ has either a single subgroup of index $2$, when the group is cyclic, or exactly three, when it is the Klein $4$-group). Since this field contains the three distinct intermediate field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$, it cannot *also* contain the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, which is distinct from those three.

For your second question, the answer is likewise "yes". The only intermediate fields of degree $2$ are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, where $d$ is the of some (but at least one) of the $p_i$. You can prove it by induction on $n$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!