# Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I want to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$. I saw [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124120/determine-the-irreducible-polynomial-for-alpha-sqrt3-sqrt5-over-mathb), but I really don't know in what it's conclusive. I don't see how he get the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt 5$. By the way, since $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3+\sqrt 5)$, the minimal polynomial a priori doesn't exist, no ? Or maybe there is something I don't get.

Comment: First of all set $X=\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$ and try to find a polynomial vanishing at $X$. Then ask yourself if there could be one of smaller degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same minimum polynomial as over $\Bbb Q$. Otherwise one
of these would be the minimum polynomial:
$$X-\sqrt3-\sqrt5,$$
$$(X-\sqrt3-\sqrt5)(X-\sqrt3+\sqrt5),$$
$$(X-\sqrt3-\sqrt5)(X+\sqrt3-\sqrt5),$$
$$(X-\sqrt3-\sqrt5)(X+\sqrt3+\sqrt5)$$
would be. But you can check, at your leisure, that none have coefficients
in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{10})$.

It may help to note that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$
has degree $8$ over $\Bbb Q$ by Kummer theory.

Comment: Thanks. But why is it important to note that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)/\mathbb Q$ has degree $8$ ?

Comment: @MSE It's a power of $2$, so all minimal polynomials must have $2$-power degree.

Comment: thank you. But one thing is strange; how can we find the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$ whereas $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)$ ?

Comment: They are all subfields of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$. @MSE