# Prove that $[ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]=8.$

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Compute  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}).$

**Here my attempt:**

Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}).$ Proved that $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]=8$, compute $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q})$ is easy, in fact it will be $$\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q})=\langle \sigma_2,\sigma_3,\sigma_5\rangle,$$ with $\sigma_k$ the automorphism that interchanges $\sqrt{k}$ with $-\sqrt{k}$ and doesn't move the rest of the elements.

I prove that $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]=8$ as follows. I do some observations first:

- If a group $G$ verifies $|G|=4$ then $G$ is isomorphic to $C_4$ (cyclic group of order 4) or to $\mathbb{V}$ (vierergruppe). In particular, $G$ can only have $1$ or $3$ proper subgroups.
- Clearly $\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension since $\mathbb{K}$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $p(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-5).$
- We have the four strict chains of extensions, all distinct:

  1. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{K}.$
  2. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{K}.$
  3. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \subset \mathbb{K}.$
  4. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}) \subset \mathbb{K}.$

Let $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Clearly $[\mathbb{L}:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{L}(\sqrt{5}).$ Then, $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{L}] \in \{1,2\}.$
With this, we have $$[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{L}][\mathbb{L}:\mathbb{Q}]=4[\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L}].$$ Therefore, $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]\in \{4,8\}.$

If we suppose that $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, then, since it is a Galois extension, $|\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q})|=4$ and the Galois correspondence joint with the fact about groups of four elements mentioned above tells us that there is only $1$ or $3$ stricts chains of extensions starting with $\mathbb{Q}$ and ending at $\mathbb{K}.$ But we found $4$ of such chains, and this concludes that must be $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]=8.$

**End.**

Is correct my solution? Could it be improved? I'm interested in reading other possible solutions and better if it's "faster". How do I prove this result without the using of group theory?

Thanks to everyone!

**Edit:**

I thought that my solution to the problem has not been posted yet in MSE but I found a question that has my solution as an answer.

[Showing field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}$ degree 8 [duplicate]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36129/showing-field-extension-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5-mathbbq-de?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Other related questions are:

[The square roots of different primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of)

I'm sorry for duplicating this question.

Comment: This is a nice solution, if you ask me. And it also generalizes. See my answer [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619). Mind you, given that you came up with this way of thinking about it I'm sure you would have come up with the generalization to more primes as well :-)

Comment: And, if you study the thread I linked, do take a look at Bill Dubuque's answer as well. It gets a way with a bit more primitive tools (doesn't use Galois groups).

Comment: Thanks for your comments @JyrkiLahtonen. I felt that a generalization of this galois-type argument for more prime numbers could be possible, but I didn't write down my ideas. The answer of Bill Dubuque is an elegant and simple solution, but I like to use Galois groups since I think it is the natural place for studying fields and extensions.

Comment: I agree. That's why I wrote my answer in the end. Using Galois theory means that the only arithmetic fact we need to prove is that $\sqrt n\notin \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$ whenever both $n$ and $m$ are square free.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've posted a new question related to field/Galois theory. I'm interested in your opinion. Here the link "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095247/proving-that-mathbbq-sqrt-sqrtpq-sqrtq-sqrt-sqrtpq-sqrtq". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is essentially true, however I feel it can be shortened by proving that $\sqrt{5} \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. To see this you can use the fact that $\text{Gal}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}) = \langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Now the quadratic subfields are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ and obviously $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is not any of them and so $\sqrt{5} \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Thus we must have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$. From here we conclude that:

$$\text{Gal}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})/\mathbb{Q}) = \langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3,\sigma_5\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$

On the other way if you want to avoid group theory you can prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$, as it's been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93453/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrtp-1-sqrtp-2-ldots-sqrtp-n-mat?rq=1). Then you can explicitly prove that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of degree $8$ and conclude that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$. Once you have this finding the Galois group is an easy task. However I feel this way requires far more work.

Comment: I like your solution! Clearly, is more direct than mine. Thanks for your answer. Could be extended by induction the Galois-type argument in order to solve the problem posed in the question you linked?

Comment: @AlgebraicallyClosed I suppose you can use such an argument to prove that the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\cdots,\sqrt{p_n})$ is $(\mathbb Z_2)^n$. However the problem is proving that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{p_n})$ is extension of order $2^n$

Comment: Okay, now I see the problem. Thanks for the time you dedicated to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating things. The index $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5):\mathbb Q]$ is just the dimension of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, which is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{3}{k}=1+3+3+1=8.$$

Comment: How do you have directly this? Are you supposing that \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} and \sqrt{5} are linearly independent? I don't see trivial this part of the problem. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered!) many times : the degree over Q of  Q($\sqrt p_1,..., \sqrt p_n$), where the $p_i$ are $n$ distinct primes, is equal to $2^n$. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609061/30070S