# How to prove $1$,$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, radicals

How do I prove that $1$,$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$? $\mathbb{Q}$ is the rational field.

I want to know the detail about the proof. Thanks in advance.

Actually I know any two of them and three of them are linearly independent.

Comment: @t.b.: Surely not...the question here is "does there exist $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{Q}$ not all zero such that $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}=0$", while the question you link to boils down to $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$, which is an illegal move here...

Comment: @t.b.:  Not quite (thought not unrelated).  For example, $\sqrt{6}$ is certainly in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, but isn't in the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space generated by $1$, $\sqrt{2}$, and $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Actually, @user1729, Bill Dubuque's answer in the linked question *does* in fact answer this question (and some more). And the fact that $b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} \not\in Q(\sqrt{6})$ (as demonstrated below by Martin) is basically how one shows (in an elementary way) that $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) \neq Q(\sqrt{6})$ (Alvaro's proof in the linked question). That is to say I agree with t.b. that this question is an _abstract_ duplicate of the other, though whether it should be closed as such is another matter.

Comment: See [this blog post by Qiaochu](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/), and [the linked file](http://www.thehcmr.org/issue2_1/mfp.pdf) from there.

Comment: @WillieWong:  Yeah, I had a similar paragraph written before I decided to scrap it in favor of "though not unrelated."  In any case, I more or less agree, though it's unclear to me the extent to which the existence of repeatable answers implies that the questions themselves are duplicate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have no doubt that many slick solutions will be given here. I'll try to post an elementary one; which uses perhaps the most straightforward approach I can imagine. (The only things that are needed are some algebraic manipulation and basic properties of rational numbers; such as that the only solution of $x^2=6y^2$ in $\mathbb Q$ are $x=y=0$.)

---

This is equivalent to showing that if
$$a+b\sqrt6=c\sqrt3+d\sqrt2$$
then $a=b=c=d=0$.

By squaring both sides of the above equation we get
$$
\begin{align*}
a^2+6b^2+2ab\sqrt6&=3c^2+2d^2+2cd\sqrt6\\
2(ab-cd)\sqrt6=3c^2+2d^2-a^2-6b^2
\end{align*}
$$
Since $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q$, this implies
$$
\begin{align*}
ab-cd&=0\\
3c^2+2d^2-a^2-6b^2&=0
\end{align*}
$$
which is the same as
$$
\begin{align*}
ab&=cd\\
3c^2+2d^2&=a^2+6b^2
\end{align*}
$$

Suppose that $b\ne0$, $c\ne0$. (I'll leave the solution of these cases to the reader.) Then we can rewrite the first equation as $\frac ac = \frac db = x$, where $x\in\mathbb Q$. Now the second equation becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
3c^2+2x^2b^2&=x^2c^2+6b^2\\
x^2(2b^2-c^2)&=3(2b^2-c^2)\\
(x^2-3)(2b^2-c^2)&=0
\end{align*}$$
This implies that $x^2=3$ or $2b^2=c^2$. None of them has non-zero solutions in rational numbers.

---

Alternatively, we could solve the case $b=0$ first. Once we're looking only at $b\ne0$, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $b=1$. (After dividing both sides with $b$.)

So we're looking at $a+\sqrt6=c\sqrt2+d\sqrt2$. And squaring, as above, gives us now $a=cd$. Thus we get
\begin{align*}
cd-c\sqrt2-d\sqrt3+\sqrt6&=0\\
(c-\sqrt3)(d-\sqrt2)&=0
\end{align*}
which means that $c=\sqrt3$ or $d=\sqrt2$. In either case, it is the contradiction with the assumption $c,d\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Is there any general method for solving such problems?

Comment: @Norbert I think that having look at these questions could help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-ration and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93459/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt6 Perhaps someone who has better knowledge of field theory and Galois theory than me could give you a better answer.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak:I think I have got your idea.Thanks.And I have read a version of proof that it first gives any two of them and any three of them are linearly independent.After having read your solution,I want to ask whether the version I read before is useful or not.Is it necessary to do like that?And one more question,is there any proof that based on any other different theory and can be presented in an elementary way like yours?

Comment: @Andylang: The parts which I "left for the reader" are using the fact that three/two of them are linearly independent. (But you probably don't need to do all possible triples.) For different proofs just check the comments under your question.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak:Got it.

Comment: Hi :-) in these days I'm receiving negative votes almost every day but I can't understand the motivation for a positive vote on this question of mine that has been appreciated by so many users. Please you can see if there are any obvious anomalies on my questions/answers. My best regards.

Answer (score 48):

Observe that $a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} = 0$ if and only if $(a + b\sqrt{2}) + (c + d\sqrt{2})\sqrt{3} = 0$. Hence it is enough to show that $\sqrt{3}$ and $1$ are independent over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, but this is equivalent to showing that $\sqrt{3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, or that $\sqrt{3}$ cannot be written as $a + b\sqrt{2}$. This is obvious (square both sides and play with the result).

Answer (score 15):

**HINT** $\ $ Specialize the Lemma below to $\rm\ K = \mathbb Q,\ a,b\ =\ 2,3\:. $

**LEMMA** $\rm\ \ [K(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}) : K]\ =\ 4\ $ if  $\rm\ \sqrt{a},\ \sqrt{b},\ \sqrt{a\:b}\ $  all are not in $\rm\:K\:$ and $\rm\: 2\: \ne\: 0\:$ in $\rm\:K\:.$

**Proof** $\ \ $  Let  $\rm\ L = K(\sqrt{b})\:.\:$ Then $\rm\:  [L:K] = 2\:$  via  $\rm\:\sqrt{b}  \not\in K\:,\:$  so it is sufficient to prove $\rm\: [L(\sqrt{a}):L] = 2\:.\:$ It fails only if  $\rm\:\sqrt{a} \in L = K(\sqrt{b})\ $ and then $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\  r + s\ \sqrt{b}\ $  for $\rm\ r,s\in K\:.\:$ But that is impossible since squaring yields $\rm(1):\ \ a\ =\ r^2 + b\ s^2 + 2\:r\:s\  \sqrt{b}\:,\: $ which contradicts hypotheses as follows:

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad rs \ne 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{b}\ \in\  K\ \ $ by solving $(1)$ for $\rm\sqrt{b}\:,\:$ using  $\rm\:2 \ne 0$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\  s = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \ \sqrt{a}\ \in\  K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\ r \in K$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\  r = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{a\:b}\in K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\ s\ \sqrt{b}\:,\: \ $times $\rm\:\sqrt{b}\quad\quad$ **QED**

**REMARK** $\ $ By induction, the lemma easily generalizes to algebraic extensions generated by adjoining $\rm\:n\:$ square-roots, see [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242) on Besicovic's Theorem, which includes references to generalizations by Mordell and Siegel. These results are elementary special cases of the Galois theory of Kummer extensions.

Comment: A general explanation.It is useful.Thank you