# Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) \times \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ if I prove $\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3$ are L.I. over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, extension-field, intuition

I proved that $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$ and $\{1,\sqrt 3\}$ are respective bases of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ over $\mathbb Q$. I want to show in some sense that since $\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3$ are Linearly Independent over $\mathbb Q$, that the product of the bases $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$ and $\{1,\sqrt 3\} =\{1,\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3, \sqrt 6\}$ is exactly a base $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$

Can this make sense?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it works, see the duplicate (or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96946/how-to-prove-1-sqrt2-sqrt3-and-sqrt6-are-linearly-independent-ove?rq=1)). We also have $[KL:\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{[K:\mathbb{Q}][L:\mathbb{Q}]}{[K\cap L:\mathbb{Q}]}$ for $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $L=\Bbb Q({\sqrt{3}})$.

Comment: In fact the indepedence result generalizes to any number of radicals as long as the radicands are multiplicatively independent - [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242)