# Show that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + X + 1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How do I show that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + X + 1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: For the second part, see [$\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+2)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575213/mathbb-qx-x21-is-not-isomorphic-to-mathbb-qx-x22), and apply it in the same way to $x^2+x+1$. Derek Holt's comment also answers this immediately.

Comment: Now it is a duplicate of the second link, after you have edited the question.  Since there is an element $a$ with $a^2+1=0$ in the second field, it must be also an element $b$ with $b^2+1=0$ in the first field, which is not the case. Hence the two fields are not isomorphic.