# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ in field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ in field extension?

We know that,  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{5})$.
Also, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(a\sqrt{2}+ b\sqrt{5})$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

If the question is true, then for which values of $a$ & $b$ can $\sqrt{10}$ be expressed in the form $a\sqrt{2}+ b\sqrt{5}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Look at degrees.

Comment: No. $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}] = \{ a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{5}+ d\sqrt{10} : a,b,c,d, \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: For no values $(a,b)$.  And the question has answer No.

Comment: You can show $\sqrt{10} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$ but that $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ and $\sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$. Can you see why? Also, as someone else noted, look at the degrees of the field extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{6})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93459/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment suggested, look at degrees over the rationals:

$$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt5):\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)(\sqrt5):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]\cdot [\Bbb Q(\sqrt2):\Bbb Q]=2\cdot2=4$$

since $\;x^2-5\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)[x]\;$ is irreducible here (proof?)

On the other side

$$[\Bbb Q\sqrt{10}:\Bbb Q]=2$$

since x$\;x^2-10\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ is irreducible here.

Comment: OK. I understand it. Due to the degree, Q(square root(2),cube root(7))=Q(square root(2)+cube root(7)) as well as =Q(square root(2).cube root(7)).As the degrees are equal. Am I right?

Comment: Don't understand your question, @SayantanPanja

Comment: I want to say that, [(Q(square root(2),cube root(7)):Q]=6=[(Q(square root(2).cube root(7)):Q]=[(Q(square root(2)+cube root(7)):Q]. So can we write that, Q(square root(2),cube root(7))=Q(square root(2).cube root(7))=Q(square root(2)+cube root(7))?

Comment: Well, yes we can...but only if you prove something else. For example, $\;[\Bbb Q(\sqrt2):\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt5):\Bbb Q]=2\;$ , yet $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\neq\Bbb Q (\sqrt5)\;$ . Equality follows if for example one of the fields contains the other one. In your example, since clearly $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt7)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt7)\;$ , if the degrees over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ are equal then the fields are the same.

Comment: Sir, you have some mistake...My question is not root(7),it is cube root(7)

Comment: The principle is the same, @SayantanPanja, no matter what roots are those.

Comment: If it is, then how we can show that , (2^(1/2))∈Q(2^(1/2)+7^(1/3)). Further how we can show that, (7^(1/3))∈Q(2^(1/2)+7^(1/3))?..@Timbuc

Comment: That I don't know, @SayantanPanja. I suppose that you'll have to play with some nasty equations, say: $$\sqrt[3]7=a+bw+cw^2+dw^3+ew^4+fw^5\;,\;\;w:=\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]7\;,\;\;a,b,c,d,e,f\in\Bbb Q$$ Not very pretty...