# Find all integers $a,\,b,\,c$ that satisfy $a\sqrt2−b = c\sqrt3$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I don't know where to start,

Find all integers $a$, $b$, $c$ that satisfy $a\sqrt{2}−b = c\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Hint: square both sides.  Deduce that $\sqrt 2\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: $a=b=c=0$ works.  :-)

Comment: By the simple [Lemma here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/93464/242)  we deduce that $\,1,\,\sqrt{2},\,\sqrt{3}\,$ are linearly independent over $\,\Bbb Q,\,$ since none of $\,\sqrt 2,\, \sqrt 3,\, \sqrt 6\,$ are in $ \Bbb Q.\,$ So the only solution is $\,a = b = c = 0.\ $

Comment: @lulu You need to say more than that, because squaring yields $\, 2ab\sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q,\,$ but that doesn't imply $\,\sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q\,$ if $\,a\,$ or $\,b = 0.\,$ But in those cases we can deduce $\,\sqrt3\,$ or $\,\sqrt 6\in \Bbb Q.\,$ The proof is done generally in the Lemma linked in my prior comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ are linearly independent: assuming that
$$ a\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3} = b $$
we have
$$ 2a^2+3c^2-b^2=2ac\sqrt{6} $$
but $\sqrt{6}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You mean linearly independent, I’m sure.

Comment: But vadim123's comment shows $a=b=c=0$ works.

Comment: so, short of 0 , 0 , 0 you are saying that there are no integer solutions to a b and c.

Comment: If $ac\neq 0$, then $\sqrt{6}=\frac{2a^2+3c^2-b^2}{2ac}\in\mathbb Q$, contradiction. Therefore $ac=0$, i.e. either $a=0$ or $c=0$. You'll get $a=b=c=0$ using the fact that $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$ are also irrational.

Comment: @user236182 This type of argument can be done just as easy in general, e.g. see [this Lemma.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/93464/242)

Comment: @Lubin: sure, fixed, sorry.