# Recovering congruence conditions from the Hilbert class polynomial for idoneal numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Before I can ask my question, I need to introduce some terminology and background.

> **Statement 1:** Let $n$ be one of [Euler's 65 convenient numbers](http://oeis.org/A000926). Then we can find congruence conditions such that
>
> $$p=x^2+ny^2 \Leftrightarrow c_1, \ldots, c_r \mod{N}$$
> See for example this [article](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Hagedorn11.pdf) why this is possible. On a related note: one can even show that for other numbers it is impossible to provide congruence conditions (cf. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11688/why-do-congruence-conditions-not-suffice-to-determine-which-primes-split-in-non), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79342/primes-of-the-form-x2ny2-and-congruences), and page 19 [here](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/%7Ekani/papers/idoneal-f.pdf))

.

> **Statement 2:** The more general case goes as follows.
>
> [image]

.

> **Statement 3:** Finding the HCF for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ is difficult. However, when $n$ is one of Euler's 65 convenient numbers then the Hilbert class field of $K$ equals the genus field of $K$. The genus field can be easily determined as follows:
>
> [image]

---

Now, basically what I want to do is the following:

- Consider cases when the genus field equals the Hilbert class field (i.e. Euler's convenient numbers)
- Construct a primitive element for the genus field (cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93453/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrtp-1-sqrtp-2-ldots-sqrtp-n-mat))
- Next, from the minimal polynomial of the Hilbert class field, I want to recover congruence conditions through quadratic reciprocity.

**Two worked out examples:**

1. The genus field of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is $M=K(\sqrt{5})=K(i)$. Now, the Hilbert class field equals the genus field, so the minimal polynomial for the primitive element $i$ is $x^2 + 1$. From the above theorem we get the condition that
   $$x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$$
   must be solvable. But this just means that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Together with the other condition of the theorem, which says that $-5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, we find that:
   $$p = x^2 + 5y^2 \Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1,9 \mod{20}$$
2. The genus field of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-21})$ is $M=K(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{-7})$. To calculate the minimal polynomial for the primitive element $\sqrt{-3} + \sqrt{-7}$, we use [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal%20polynomial%20sqrt%28-3%29%2bsqrt%28-7%29):
   $$f(x)=x^4+20x^2+16=(x^2+10)^2-84$$
   This polynomial is solvable modulo $p$ if
   $$y^2 \equiv 84 \mod{p}$$
   is solvable, AND
   $$x^2 \equiv - 10 \mod{p}$$
   has a solution. Each condition can, via quadratic reciprocity, be expressed by a congruence, and putting the different congruences together (via the AND operator) gives us again a congruence condition.

**Problem:**

The above method seems to break down when we consider more than $2$ elements. (eg. $\sqrt{-3}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{-7}$). Wolfram does not give a nice "recursive quadratic" polynomial. However, I suspect that congruence conditions can be recovered in a similar way.

Comment: Why do you want to use this roundabout method? Finding the primes represented by all the forms in a genus, taken together, is pretty easy, see Cox Corollary 2.27, page 36 for principal genus. If there is only one form (class) per genus, finished.

Comment: For example, $x^2 + 105 y^2$ represents all primes $p$ with  $$ p \equiv  1,  109,  121,  169,  289,  361 \pmod {420}.$$ Note that $23^2 - 420 = 109.$

Comment: I am aware of the approach via genus theory, quadratic forms, etc. The motivation of my question is the following: I am writing my MA thesis and can 'only' spend 40-50 pages. I decided to leave out PART I of Cox. However, I hoped that I could recover some important results of it with the techniques of PART II.

Comment: Take a look at Hudson_Williams and Liu_Williams at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.html , you might as well know what really happens with more than one per genus.