# Minimum degree rational equation with root $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

What is the minimum degree of an equation with **rational** coefficients that has a root $x=a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$ with $a,b,c,d$ primes numbers?

I know how to find an equation of second degree that has root $a+\sqrt{b}$
$$
x=a+\sqrt{b} \quad \rightarrow \quad (x-a)^2=b 
$$

and a $4-$degree equation that has root $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$ 
$$
x=a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c} \quad \rightarrow \quad (x-a)^2=(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2 \quad \rightarrow \quad  \left[(x-a)^2-b-c \right]^2=4bc
$$

But it seems that this simple  method cannot be used for a root with more than two surds.  There is it some other method?

Comment: It will be degree eight. This is a primitive element of the field extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt b,\sqrt c,\sqrt d)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. The question is also a special case of [this older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93453/11619). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619) for a proof of the fact that the above field extension is of degree eight.

Comment: Anyway, the minimal polynomial has zeros $a\pm \sqrt b\pm\sqrt c\pm\sqrt d$. All sign combinations occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=a+ \sqrt{b}+ \sqrt{c}+ \sqrt{d}$  square this and move some terms around
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-a)^2+b-c-d = -2(x-a)\sqrt{b}+ 2\sqrt{c} \sqrt{d}
\end{eqnarray*}
Square it again and move some more terms around
\begin{eqnarray*}
((x-a)^2+b-c-d)^2 -4b(x-a)^2-4cd = -8(x-a)\sqrt{b}\sqrt{c} \sqrt{d}
\end{eqnarray*}
Squaring one final time & we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(((x-a)^2+b-c-d)^2 -4b(x-a)^2-4cd)^2 = 64(x-a)^2bcd
\end{eqnarray*}
So the equation that this quantity satisfies an equation of degree $\color{red}{8}$ as expected.

Comment: How will you prove that this is *minimum* degree polynomial with that  required root?

Comment: @JaideepKhare I have shown that $8$ is an upper bound on the degree & there are probably situtations where a lower value will work ... E.g. $d=bc$ ... I am not sure at the moment to make my answer completely sound ... You are right there is still something left to prove.

Comment: @JaideepKhare That is a bit delicate. If $b,c,d$ are distinct primes (what was probably intended), it turns out that 8 is the minimum degree. You need the machinery of field extensions (possibly also Galois theory) to prove this. See the questions I linked to for the arguments. Took me a while to check the end result. Hence the belated +1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Than that's beyond my scope.(Presently, because I am a highschool student)

Comment: @JaideepKhare It is not out of the question that you would get at least the rough idea from a suitable book. WP [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension) may be too sketchy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for that! I will surely read that.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit How can your final result be $64(x-a)^2 bcd$ ?