# Polynomial having rational coefficients and one root: $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> Form a polynomial of **smallest degree** having rational coefficients and one root as $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$

**Idea 1:**

I thought that other roots would be just different combination of signs on the surds, ie

- $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$
- $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$

so least degree would be $2^3 = 8$.

Polynomial then could be formed using viete's formulas.

**Idea 2:**

We let $x = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$. Then rearranging and squaring repeatedly gives us the polynomial.

**Questions**

1. This method seems unsatisfactory and is just a thought. Please help me with a proper method.
2. Is the polynomial i found unique? or there are more polynomials with rational coefficients with this root ($\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$)?
3. Also can we generalise this result: that the least degree of a polynomial whose root is a sum of $n$ distinct surds is $\sum \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$ ?

**Edit**

As stated by **Hagen Von Elitzen**, the result in third question is correct only for square roots of numbers which are pairwise coprime. Eg. ($\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}$) and not ($\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{10}$)

Comment: Very similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234480/minimum-degree-rational-equation-with-root-a-sqrtb-sqrtc-sqrtd/2234514#2234514

Comment: Repeated squaring and rearranging is not a bad way to get at _a_ polynomial with your number as root.

Comment: @Donald Thank you but i tried that method. How can we say if there are $n$ such surds in sum as a root, then degree will be $2^n$?

Comment: Knowing that the degree is at most $2^n$ is trivial once you get into some basic field extension theory. Each successive square root either doubles the degree or leaves it unchanged. However, finding the polynomial becomes rather difficult eventually.

Comment: There are $2^n$ values of the form $ \pm \sqrt{x_1} \pm \sqrt{x_2} \cdots \pm \sqrt{x_n}$. We will need all of them to be roots of our minimal polynomial. This will become clearer if you study some field & Galois theory.

Comment: Ok I understand that I need to read more before I understand. Can you suggest a reference, preferably a book or website?

Comment: I think you mean smallest nonzero polynomial.

Comment: With $\varphi = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 5$, then ${\varphi}^k$ will always be of the form $M_0 + M_1 \sqrt 2 + M_2 \sqrt 3 + M_3 \sqrt 5 + M_4 \sqrt 6 + M_5 \sqrt 10 + M_6 \sqrt 15 + M_7 \sqrt 30$.  You can use this to turn the question into a linear algebra problem by expanding $P(\varphi) = 0$ for variable coefficients.  It is a lot of work, not something you would want to do by hand.

Comment: The 8 solutions are all the possible combinations $\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{3}\pm\sqrt{5}$

Comment: $2^n$ is correct only for "independent" surds. Degree $4$ suffices for $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3+\sqrt 6$, for example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for correction! But tell me will the equation be unique?

Comment: @akhmeteni Up to multiplication by a constant, yes. (Or: If we demand the leading coefficient is $1$, then yes). This follwos because if $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are of minimal degree with leading coefficient $1$, then $f(X)-g(X)$ would be of lesser degree.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you but does there exist $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ who have that root so that $g(x) \neq k f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a partial answer.

Your idea does indeed work. If you apply it, then you will get the polynomial$$p(x)=x^8-40x^6+353x^4-960x^2+576.$$Asserting that it is a polynomial with the smallest degree within the non-null polynomials of which $\sqrt2+\sqrt3-\sqrt5$ is a root is the same thing as asserting that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Right now, I don't see how to prove it. Now, assume that it is true. Then, if $q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]\setminus\{0\}$ is such that $q\bigl(\sqrt2+\sqrt3-\sqrt5\bigr)=0$, I will prove that the degree of $q(x)$ is greater than or equal to $8$.

Since $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have a common root, then they are *not* relatively prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Therefore, there is a non-constant polynomial $r(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that divides both of them. But, since $p(x)$ is irreducible, this means that $r(x)$ can only be of the form $\lambda p(x)$, for some $\lambda\in\mathbb Q$. But then $p(x)$ itself divides $q(x)$ and therefore the degree of $q(x)$ is greater than than or equal to the degree of $p(x)$, which is $8$.

Comment: It seems my knowledge is insufficient to understand your answer at the moment. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @akhmeteni That's a good reason to learn more!

Answer (score 3):

> If $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ has $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$ as a root,
>   then it has all eight numbers $\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3} \pm \sqrt{5}$
>   as roots. So the smallest degree of your polynomial is $8$.

The reason is that we have some automorphisms over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$. One is 
$$\sigma(\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2} \quad \sigma(\sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{3}  \quad \sigma(\sqrt{5}) = -\sqrt{5}$$ This automorphism also fixes $\mathbb{Q}$

Assume $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ has $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$ as root, write $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_n x^n$, $\alpha = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}, \beta = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$. Then we have $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta$.

We have $a_0 + a_1 \alpha + ... +a_n \alpha^n = 0$, taking $\sigma$ on both sides give
$$\sigma(a_0)+\sigma(a_1)\sigma(\alpha) + ... + \sigma(a_n)\sigma(\alpha)^n = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad a_0 + a_1 \beta + ... + a_n \beta^n = 0$$
Hence $f(\alpha) = 0$ implies $f(\beta) = 0$.

Using the same argument, we can show that all remaining 7 numbers are roots. Proving the existence of these automorphisms has to resort to Galois theory.

Comment: The existence of the automorphism stated above is equivalent to the fact that $\sqrt{5}$ does not belong to the field generated by the other two radicals. So in a way this is a circular argument, unless you also prove the fact. But this is not that hard. There are exactly three quadratic fields contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, the obvious ones.

Comment: There is nothing circular here. The Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ has order eight, so the desired automorphism exists, of course the information of Galois group immediately implies $\sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 2):

The degree of a linear combination of $n$ square roots may be less than $2^n$, like in the case of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! So the numbers under roots must be pairwise co-prime.

Comment: @akhmeteni: In fact, a weaker condition is enough, independence of the numbers in the $\mathbb{Z}/2$ vector space $\mathbb{Q^*}/(\mathbb{Q^*})^2$, like for instance $2\cdot 3$, $2\cdot 5$ and $3\cdot 5$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a systematic method based on linear algebra:

- Let $\alpha = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}$.
  Note that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$.
- Write the matrix $A$ of the linear map $x \mapsto \alpha x$ in the basis 
  $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15},\sqrt{30}$.
- Find the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: You wouldn't  know apriori that is a basis.