# Showing that $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2} + \sqrt{5})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I am attempting to show that $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2} + \sqrt{5})$, where $p > 2$ is prime. I have already shown that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2p$.

If needs be, I can understand that this might constitute proving that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2} + \sqrt{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}, \sqrt{5})$, which I know intuitively but am unsure how to prove. In that regard, I am aware of questions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93463/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93453/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrtp-1-sqrtp-2-ldots-sqrtp-n-mat), but all answers provided either

- do not seem to generalize easily to cases where not both of the roots are square.
- are beyond the scope of my current course.

Any help towards a (preferably low-level) proof of either the inclusion of $\sqrt{5}$ or the equality of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2} + \sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}, \sqrt{5})$ is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So let $\alpha = \sqrt [p]2+\sqrt 5$ then $$\left(\alpha -\sqrt 5\right)^p=2$$

Expand the left-hand side using the binomial theorem to obtain $$p(\alpha)-q(\alpha)\sqrt 5=2$$ where $q(\alpha)\gt 0$ since all the terms involving $\sqrt 5$ have the same sign. Also $p(\alpha), q(\alpha)$ are polynomials in $\alpha$ and belong to $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$
 Finally $$\sqrt 5=\frac {p(\alpha)-2}{q(\alpha)}$$

Comment: Wow, surprisingly straightforward!

Comment: The full expansion of $(\alpha - \sqrt{5})^p$ would have alternating signs, would it not? So initially I'm unsure what you mean that "all the terms involving $\sqrt{5}$ have the same sign". But more importantly, it would feature all powers of $\sqrt{5}$ from $0$ to $p$, right? So how can we factorize out $\sqrt{5}$ and be left with a polynomial $q(\alpha)$ purely over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: @ENPM Note that powers of $\sqrt{5}$ are either rational, or $\sqrt{5}$ times a rational. The former terms come with a positive sign, the latter with negative sign.

Comment: @ENPM $(-\sqrt 5)^1=-\sqrt 5; (-\sqrt 5)^2=5; (-\sqrt 5)^3=-5\sqrt 5$ - the powers which are not integers have a factor $\sqrt 5$ and a negative sign.

Comment: @Wojowu Of course! How silly of me.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: I could not delete the answer I was working on fast enough when I saw this! I love the 'Finally' punchline, but it could be improved with 'Finally, using some more algebra.'..

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer which uses some elementary properties of field automorphisms (essentially the statement that degree $2$ extension is Galois, but this is something which can be rather easily proven directly using just field theory).

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt{5})$. Suppose $\sqrt{5}\not\in K$. Then $K(\sqrt{5})$ is a degree $2$ extension of $K$, which implies there exists an automorphism $\sigma$ of $K(\sqrt{5})/K$ such that $\sigma(\sqrt{5})=-\sqrt{5}$. Since $\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt{5}\in K$, it is fixed by $\sigma$, so we have
$$\sigma(\sqrt[p]{2})=\sigma(\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5})=\sigma(\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt{5})-\sigma(\sqrt{5})=\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}.$$

However, $\sqrt[p]{2}+2\sqrt{5}$ is not a conjugate of $\sqrt[p]{2}$. Indeed, since $p>2$, the nontrivial conjugates of $\sqrt[p]{2}$ are not real numbers, and clearly $\sqrt[p]{2}+2\sqrt{5}\neq\sqrt[p]{2}$. This is a contradiction, so we conclude $\sqrt{5}\in K$ after all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunately, though I roughly understand your answer, it introduces ideas not on my course and does not seem elementary enough. Thank you again for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use Galois theory, we can just rule out the possibilities $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}]=1,2,p$ by more elementary means (I assume you can use results such as tower law).

Clearly $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[p]{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$, or else $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2)\ni\sqrt5$, contradiction.

Start with
$$
(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5)^n=\sum\binom{n}{k}\sqrt[p]2^{n-k}\sqrt5^k
$$
Since $p>2$, we immediately get, by considering the $\sqrt[p]2^2$ coefficient in any possible linear dependence, that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}]\neq 2$ (recall you have $\{\sqrt[p]2^j\sqrt5^k\mid 0\leq j<p; k=0,1\}$ as a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt5)$).

If $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}]=p$, then $x=\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt5$ satisfies both $(x-\sqrt{5})^p-2=0$ and another monic polynomial (over $\mathbb{Q}$) $m(x)=0$ of degree $p$.  Expanding,
\begin{align*}
x^p-\sqrt{5}px^{p-1}+\binom{p}25x^{p-2}-\dots-5^{(p-1)/2}\sqrt5&=0\\
x^p+m_1x^{p-1}+m_2x^{p-2}+\dots+m_p &=0
\end{align*}
therefore we have
$$
\underbrace{(m_1+\sqrt{5}p)}_{\neq 0}x^{p-1}+\left[m_2-\binom{p}25\right]x^{p-2}+\dots+(m_p+5^{(p-1)/2}\sqrt5)=0
$$
Thus $x$ satisfies a nontrivial polynomial equation of degree $p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5,\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)]\leq p-1$, which contradicts $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2,\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}]=2p$.

Comment: Firstly, we don't know whether $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})\subseteq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{2}+\sqrt{5})$ (we are trying to prove this!) so the last inequality needn't make sense. Second, you say "[...] which contradicts $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}]=2p$", but we are assuming $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2+\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}]=p$ at this point. It should be possible to fix this though.

Comment: Oops, yes, $\sqrt5$ went missing.