# Sum of irrational numbers, a basic algebra problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be positive  rational numbers. If $\sqrt[l_1]{x_1},\dots,\sqrt[l_n]{x_n}$ are all irrational numbers (where $l_1,l_2,\dotsc,l_n\in\Bbb N^*$), does it follow that $$\sqrt[l_1]{x_1}+ \dotsb + \sqrt[l_n]{x_n}$$ is an irrational number, too?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: @tomasz I gess it means strictly positive integers

Comment: I mean integers no smaller than $0$. What does it matter? I'm not the one who asked the question, am I? On the other hand, if I wrote $\mathbb N^*$, I would probably have meant some saturated extension of natural numbers, or the natural numbers within a saturated extension of reals.

Comment: I asked OP what he meant by a symbol whose meaning I'm not sure about. Why would *I* need to explain anything? Maybe that's what he meant, but it still doesn't hurt to ask (or clarify where there's confusion...).

Comment: See the papers by Mordell and Siegel that I cite in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242) (the radicands need to be multiplicatibvely independents).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is and old question and the answer is yes.

Mordell was interested in a particular case of this problem in his paper [On the linear independence of algebraic numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-3/On-the-linear-independence-of-algebraic-numbers/pjm/1103051334.full).

Later on, Ursell in the paper [*The degrees of radical extensions*](https://cms.math.ca/publications/cmb/) solves this problem in the particular case $x_i\in\mathbb N^*$ and $(x_i,x_j)=1$ for $i\neq j$.

In fact, the problem can be easily reduced to the case where $x_i\in\mathbb N^*$ and $l_1=\cdots=l_n$. This is in fact a [problem](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=elemat-001:1981:36::25&id=browse&id2=browse4&id3=) proposed/solved by Preda Mihailescu long time go. Later on Toma Albu worked on this problem from different point of view and proved this as Theorem 2.2 in this survey [paper](http://imar.ro/%7Edbeltita/IMAR_preprints/2010/2010_7.pdf). Basically he proved the theorem in an older [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X92901318) where he acknowledges that his results have appeared in many other sources, such as Karpilovski's book *Field Theory*.

Anyway, the proof given by Mihailescu is the most "elementary" and I suggest you to try to read it (well, maybe using Google translate).

Comment: The link to a paper (or whatever that is) by Mihailescu is dead. Could you provide a reference as to what you were linking to?

Comment: Mission 835 of  page(23:19)
https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN378850199_0036?tify={%22pages%22:[23],%22panX%22:0.41,%22panY%22:0.503,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.496}

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment.

Your problem is actually equivalent to the following:

**Problem:** If $a_1,..,a_k$ are positive integers, and $m$ is a positive integer, so that $\sqrt[m]{a_i} \notin \mathbb Q$ then

$$\sum \sqrt[m]{a_i} \notin \mathbb Q \,$$

You can do the reduction to this problem in two steps:

**Step 1:** Let $m=lcm (l_1,..,l_n)$. Then $\frac{1}{l_i}=\frac{k_i}{m}$.
Let $y_i=x_i^{k_i}$.

Then, you know that $y_i$ are positive rational numbers and $x_i^\frac{1}{l_i}=\sqrt[m]{y_i}$.

**Step 2:** Let $y_i=\frac{b_i}{c_i}$ and let $d= lcm (c_1,..,c_n)$. Then you can write

$$y_i=\frac{a_i}{d^m}$$

and you get that problem.

I am pretty sure that I saw some Theorems in Galois Theory which imply stronger versions of the above problem.

**Added**   Theorem 2.9  in [This Paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/ASUO/mathematics/pdf23/Albu.pdf) is exactly the question asked, it provides some reference to the History of the problem and a proof.

Comment: This is true at least if $a_i$ are coprime and $m=2$, and the proof is quite a bit more involved than one could think at first glance; elementary methods work for $n=3$, but I think they fail as soon as $n=4$. That is, if I recall correctly from my abstract algebra classes. :)

Comment: @tomasz I actually found a reference, which proves the asked question ;) If I remember right, the issue with the relatively primess is that otherwise the radicals could cancel, which is not the case because of the positivity..... And I remember a very nice elementary proof for $m=2$, which cannot be extended:)