# If $a$ and $b$ are both irrational, is $a+b$ also irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am working out of *Calculus* by Spivak (4th ed.) and have come across a question which I would like some further insight on.

*If $a$ and $b$ are both irrational, is $a+b$ necessarily irrational?*

I have already proved that if $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational then $a+b$ is irrational.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(1+\sqrt{2})+(1-\sqrt{2})=2$.

Comment: i think no take $$a=\sqrt{2},b=1-\sqrt{2}$$ and $$a+b=1$$ rational

Comment: $\sqrt{2} + (-\sqrt{2}) = 0$

Comment: Lots of counterexamples here, so maybe you could write your own answer! We love that!

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499784/sum-of-irrational-numbers-are-there-nontrivial-examples.

Comment: This is a very frustrating question.  The obvious counter example is $r$ rational and $a$ irrational then $b =r-a$ is irrational and $a+b =r$.  To which one very much wants to say "okay, but what about two irrationals that aren't related to each other; two independent irrationals" to which the answer is "what do you mean by independent" so you say "$b\ne r-a$ for any rational $r$" to which the response is "$b\ne r-a \iff a+b\ne r$.  What you said is redundant".  You're left feeling somehow you've been duped.  But you haven't.  Yes, I've been there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to answer the contrapositive, if you don't just see the answer. The contrapositive is: "if $a+b$ is rational, is it the case that at least one of $a$ and $b$ is rational?". Since you've already proved that irrational plus rational is irrational, this is just "if $a+b$ is rational, is it the case that both $a$ and $b$ are rational?". This slightly different perspective might make it easier for you to find an example.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$a=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1-\sqrt{2}$ are both irrational and $a+b=2$