# Non-trivial examples of irrational numbers $x, y$ such that $x - y$ is rational.

Tags: irrational-numbers, quotient-group

If we factor the additive group $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb Q$ we will have the quotient group $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$ where $\mathbb Q$ is the identity element. And I try to find non-trivial examples of irrational numbers which are in the same coset (i.e $x - y \in \mathbb Q$). Yet I am not able to come with one.

What i mean when i say "trivial" is like $x = y$ or $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = \sqrt{2} - 2$.

Comment: $x-y$ being rational means $x=y+q$ for some rational $q$ so... what do you mean by trivial precisely?

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{50}+7}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{50}-7}=2$

Comment: The problem is that $y$ will be a rational number plus $x,$ and so if we think of rational numbers as "trivial adjustments", $y$  and $x$ will be trivially different. Or, if  you have in mind a rational number that you don't consider to be trivial, then just add it to $\sqrt 2$ to get an example.

Comment: @Peter Foreman: I was going to search for an answer of mine where some examples like this show up after making my initial comment, but you beat me to it! *(3 minutes later)* Ah, here it is --- my answer to [sum of irrational numbers - are there nontrivial examples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/499816/13130).

Comment: @PeterForeman $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{50}\pm7} = \sqrt 2 \pm 1$

Comment: The intent of the question is probably an utterly unexpected case, like as $\pi-e$, if it actually would turn out to be rational (which we cannot rule out at the moment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't going to be any "non-trivial" examples. Whatever we try, we will have $y= x-q$ for some rational number $q$. We might use two different ways of describing $x$ to *camouflage* this fact (e.g. $x=\sqrt2, y=\frac{\sqrt8}{2}-2$ is a simple example), or we can cleverly hide $q$ (an example given in the comments above), but ultimately we can't change this fact.

Answer (score 4):

You can find many examples also using  appropriately  the identity $\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}=1$.

Or the identity $\ln{\frac{x}{y}}=\ln{x}-\ln{y}$

For instance take  $x=2e^3$ and $2e^2$