# Show that $({\sqrt{2}\!+\!1})^{1/n} \!+ ({\sqrt{2}\!-\!1})^{1/n}\!\not\in\mathbb Q$

Tags: induction, contest-math, radicals, rationality-testing

How could we prove that for every positive integer $n$,  the number 
$$({\sqrt{2}+1})^{1/n} + ({\sqrt{2}-1})^{1/n}$$ is irrational?

I think it could be done inductively from a more general expression, but I don't know how.

I made an effort trying to solve it using many different methods.

Comment: It's a problem from this year Polish Mathematican Olympiad.

Comment: It can be seen that equating the expression in the problem statement with $\frac{2p}{q}$ yields $(\sqrt{2}  -1)^\frac{1}{n} = \frac{p}{q} \pm \sqrt{\frac{p}{q} - 1}$. I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: @jef You can take the $n^{th}$ power of that and the right hand side will be a rational number plus a rational multiple of the square root.

Comment: Moreover, following up on my previous comment, let $c = (\sqrt{2} - 1)^\frac{1}{n}$; then $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{ -(2c+1) \pm \sqrt{-2c^2 + 4c - 3}}{2}$. Again, not sure if this helps.

Comment: To the person who voted to close: In what universe is this question "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: @jef It does help; see the answer I just added.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assume that for a certain positive integer $n$ 
$$
\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{1/n}\in \mathbb Q.
$$
Clearly, $\,\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/n}\cdot\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{1/n}=1$, and thus
$$
\left(\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{1/n}\right)^2=
\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{2/n}+2+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{2/n}
\in \mathbb Q,
$$
and hence
$$
\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{2/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{2/n}
\in \mathbb Q.
$$
Next
$$
\left(\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{1/n}\right)^3=
\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{3/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{3/n}+3\left(\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{1/n}\right),
$$
and hence
$$
\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{3/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{3/n}\in\mathbb Q.
$$
Let $s_k=\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{k/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{k/n}$. Then
$$
s_1^k=s_k+\binom{k}{1}s_{k-2}+\binom{k}{2}s_{k-4}
+\cdots+\binom{k}{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}s_{k-2\lfloor k/2\rfloor},
$$
which means that we can inductively show that 
$$
s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\in\mathbb Q.
$$
But
$$
s_n=\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)=2\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb Q,
$$
and hence
$$
s_1=\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/n}+\big(\sqrt{2}+1\big)^{1/n}\not\in\mathbb Q.
$$

**Generalization.** If $a,b\in\mathbb R$, such that
$a,b, a+b\not\in\mathbb Q$ and $ab\in\mathbb Q$, then using exactly this method, we obtain that
$a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}\not\in\mathbb Q$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 6):

Use the fact that for every $n$ there exists a  polynomial $P_n[x]$ monic of degree $n$ with integral coefficients so that we have the identity:

\begin{eqnarray*}
t^n + \frac{1}{t^n} = P_n(t+ \frac{1}{t})
\end{eqnarray*}

The $P_n$'s are  connected with the Chebyshev polynomial of first kind since for $t = e^{i \theta}$ we get $2 \cos n \theta = P_n (2 \cos \theta)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos n \theta &=& \frac{1}{2}P_n (2 \cos \theta) \\
\cos n \theta &=& T_n( \cos \theta)
\end{eqnarray*}
so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_n(x) = 2 T_n(\frac{x}{2})
\end{eqnarray*}

For instance 
\begin{eqnarray*}
T_3(x) = 4x^3 - 3 x \\
P_3(x) = 2 T_3(\frac{x}{2}) = x^3 - 3 x
\end{eqnarray*}

One checks easily the identity:

\begin{eqnarray*}
t^3 + \frac{1}{t^3} = P_3(t+\frac{1}{t})
\end{eqnarray*}

Back to our problem. We have $(\sqrt{2}-1)(\sqrt{2}+1) = 2 -1 = 1$ and so 
$(\sqrt{2}-1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1}$ and similarly for any power 
$$(\sqrt{2}-1)^{1/n}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1)^{1/n}}$$.

Let $x =(\sqrt{2} + 1)^{1/n}$. Then 
$$ x + \frac{1}{x} = (\sqrt{2}+ 1)^{1/n}  + (\sqrt{2} - 1)^{1/n}$$

Now if $x+\frac{1}{x}$ were rational then so would be $P_n(x+\frac{1}{x}) = x^n + \frac{1}{x^n} = \sqrt{2}+1 + \sqrt{2} - 1 = 2 \sqrt{2}$ which is not the case. We conclude that $x+\frac{1}{x} = (\sqrt{2}+ 1)^{1/n}  + (\sqrt{2} - 1)^{1/n}$ is irrational.

In fact $(\sqrt{2}+ 1)^{1/n}  + (\sqrt{2} - 1)^{1/n}$ is the unique positive root  of the equation $(P_n[x])^2 - 8 =0$ or $ (T_n(\frac{x}{2}))^2 = 2$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha = (1+\sqrt{2})^{1/n}$, $\beta = (-1+\sqrt{2})^{1/n}$.  Then $\alpha\beta = 1$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the polynomial $X^2-(\alpha+\beta)X+1$.

If $\alpha+\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lie in a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Since $\alpha^n = 1 + \sqrt{2}$, we have $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, and since $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, this implies that $1+\sqrt{2}$ is an $n$-th power in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

We'll show that this can't happen.  Suppose that $(a+b\sqrt{2})^n = 1+\sqrt{2}$.  We may assume that $a>0$.  Then $1=a^n + 2{n\choose 2} a^{n-2} b^2 + \cdots$ is a sum of at least two positive integers, contradiction.

Comment: It is enough to prove that $\alpha+\beta$ is not an integer because an algebraic integer that is rational must be an integer.

Comment: @lhf Is there a direct way to show this?

Comment: See the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Using elementary bounds, it is easy to prove that $1< \alpha+\beta < 3$, and so you only need to prove that $\alpha+\beta\neq 2$.

Comment: @lhf Oh, silly me, I was thinking that $\beta^{-n}$ is unbounded... but of course $\beta^{1/n}$ isn't.  You're quite right, and that makes four proofs for this problem.  Yours probably deserves to be a separate answer, since mine is (almost) purely algebraic.

Comment: I don't know a simple proof that $\alpha+\beta\ne2$ ...

Comment: @lhf Well, one simple way is that $\alpha+\beta=2$ would make $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the roots of $X^2-2X+1$. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer: (credit goes 99% to lhf)

Let $\alpha = (\sqrt{2}+1)^{1/n}$, $\beta = (\sqrt{2}-1)^{1/n}$.  Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers, $\alpha+\beta$ is an algebraic integer.  Since a rational algebraic integer is an integer, it suffices to show that $\alpha+\beta$ is not an integer.

The problem is trivial for $n=1$, so we assume $n>1$.

We have $\alpha\beta=1$, so, by AM-GM, $\alpha+\beta > 2$ ($\alpha\neq\beta$, so we do not have equality).  Furthermore, $\beta<1$ and $\alpha < (1+\sqrt{2})^{1/2} < 2$, so $\alpha+\beta<3$.  Therefore $\alpha+\beta$ is not an integer, hence not rational.