# The sum of two irrational square roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

This is very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479092/sum-of-two-irrational-radicals-is-irrational) question, but I was wondering if there was a simpler proof.  In particular, a proof that would prove that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is an irrational number if both $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ are irrational.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: If $xy$ is not a perfect square, show that $(\sqrt x + \sqrt y )^2 = x + y + 2\sqrt{ xy}$ is irrational, and use the fact that and if $u^2$ is irrational then so is $u$.

If $xy = n^2$ then show that $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt x\left(1+ \frac n {x}\right)$is irrational.

Comment: This gets about 80% of the way... but what if, e.g., $x=2$ and $y=8$?

Comment: Should get the whole way now :)

Comment: With the tiny caveat that $x$ itself can't be a rational square, of course, but this looks good!

Comment: That was implicit in the question I believe - otherwise of course the theorem is false.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thank you for your response. However, I'm still not sure how to approach the second part of your answer. Do you think you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: @just1question Well, you know that $1+\frac nx$ is rational, and $\sqrt{x}$ is irrational, so...

Answer (score 10):

If $x$ and $y$ are integers then so is $x - y$ and further if $\sqrt x + \sqrt y$ is rational then $\sqrt x - \sqrt y = \frac{x - y}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}$ is also rational. Then by sums and differences so are both $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$. Therefore if we assume that at least one of $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ are irrational than so is their sum.