# How many pairs (a, b) of positive integers are there such that $a\ge b$ and $2\left(\sqrt\frac{15}{a}+\sqrt\frac{15}{b}\right) $is an integer

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

How many pairs (a, b) of positive integers are there such that $a\ge b$  and $$2\left(\sqrt\frac{15}{a}+\sqrt\frac{15}{b}\right) $$
is an integer

From the 2013 IMC (http://imc-official.chiuchang.org/files/problem/2013-IWYMIC-Individual.pdf)

I genuinely have no idea how to solve this, hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the only solutions are when the radicals evaluate to rational numbers. Hence WLOG we can substitute $a=15m^2$ and $b=15n^2$ with $m\ge n$ giving the expression
$$2\left(\frac1m+\frac1n\right)=\frac{2m+2n}{mn}$$
So, in order for the resulting expression to be an integer, we need
$$2m+2n\equiv0\mod{mn}$$
which is equivalent to the two simultaneous equations
$$2n\equiv0\mod{m}$$
$$2m\equiv0\mod{n}$$
The first equation implies that $n=m/2$ or $n=m$ as $m\ge n\gt0$ which agrees with the second equation. In the first case ($n=m/2$), the entire original expression simplifies to
$$\frac{6}{m}$$
Hence the only possible values of $m$ and $n$ are $(m,n)=(2,1),(6,3)$ in order for the expression to be an integer. In the second case ($n=m$) we get
$$\frac{4}{m}$$
in which case the only solutions are $(m,n)=(1,1),(2,2),(4,4)$. All of these solutions for $m$ and $n$ correspond to exactly one solution for $a$ and $b$ hence there are $5$ solutions in which the expression results in an integer.

Comment: "Clearly the only solutions are when the radicals evaluate to rational numbers" or if $(\sqrt{\frac 1a} + \sqrt{\frac1 b}) = q\sqrt{15}$ for a rational $q$.  Can you claim that is only possible if $\sqrt{\frac{15}a}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{15}b}$ are both rational?

Comment: @fleablood $\sqrt{\frac{15}{a}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{15}{b}}$ either both rational or irrational as they sum to a rational (actually, an integer divided by $2$). However, as asked and shown in [The sum of two irrational square roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880081/the-sum-of-two-irrational-square-roots), in particular the answer by [Mathmo123](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154802/mathmo123), shows that the sum of two irrational square roots is always irrational. Thus, this means here that $\sqrt{\frac{15}{a}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{15}{b}}$ must both be rational.

Comment: Right... but I think that needs to be pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

From

$$a=15m^2,\\b=15n^2$$
we draw
$$2\left(\frac1m+\frac1n\right)=k$$
or
$$2(m+n)=kmn$$

where $1\le k\le4$.

By brute force, $$(m,n,k)=(4,4,1),(3,6,1),(6,3,1),(2,2,2),(1,2,3),(2,1,3),(1,1,4).$$

Comment: You should mention that you (correctly) use that the sum of square roots of rationals is rationals iff each of the summands is rational