# Let $n,m\in N0$ and $\sqrt{n}\not\in Q.$ Show that $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}\not\in Q$

Tags: proof-writing, roots, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $n,m\in  N0$  and $\sqrt{n}\not\in Q.$ Show that $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}\not\in Q$

My first thought was to prove it via Contradiction.

So, suppose $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}\in Q$

And since $\sqrt{n}\not\in Q$, we'll have whether

1.: $\sqrt{m}\not\in Q$

2.: $\sqrt{m}\in Q$

Would this be a reasonable approach in the first place?

And also how could/should I continue or approach this?

Comment: The case irrational + irrational is probably going to give you trouble, because in general you can have two irrationals that sum to a rational number. You have to use the fact that these are square roots of integers.

Comment: Yes, you can prove it via contradiction. Since $Q$ is a field, start from the definition of a field; it tells you that if $a,b \in Q$ then $a + b \in Q$. You can develop the proof from there.

Comment: Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$ and $n=da$, $m=db$. In particular $\gcd(a,b)=1$. If $r=\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{Q}\ni r^2=n+m+2d\sqrt{ab}$. Therefore $a$ and $b$ must be a squares. Let $a=x^2, b=y^2$, with $x,y>0$. Then $r=\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}=x\sqrt{d}+y\sqrt{d}=(x+y)\sqrt{d}$. Then $d$ must also be a square. But this would imply that $\sqrt{n}=x\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The sum of two irrational square roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880081/the-sum-of-two-irrational-square-roots)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}\in\mathbb Q$;

If $m$ is a square then $\sqrt{m}\in \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q $is closed under addition, i.e. $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{m}=\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb Q$ contradiction.

If $m$ is not a square then since $\mathbb Q$ is closed under division $\mathbb Q \ni\frac{n-m}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}}=\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}\in \mathbb Q$,

which means, $\frac12\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}\right)=\sqrt n\in\mathbb Q$ contradiction again.

Comment: Your first sentence assumes that $\sqrt m \in Q$.  But we are given $\sqrt of n \notin \mathbb  Q$.  You only assume m is a square, hence $\sqrt m \in \mathbb Q$ means only that $\sqrt m -  \sqrt m= 0\in \mathbb Q.$  And we already know $n\notin  Q$.  No contradiction.  You have no clue what $\sqrt n

Comment: @amWhy NO Assume $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}$ in Rationals...

Comment: Then please write that in your proof.  Assuming $\sqrt n \in \mathbb Q,$ is already a contradiction, right?   You never prove that $\sqrt n + \sqrt m \notin Q$

Comment: I'm sorry for the 'late' reply but could someone maybe explain the step for Q being closed under division?
Just like: how do you come to the conclusion that  $\sqrt{n} -\sqrt{m} =\frac{n-m}{\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{m}}$

Comment: @Chees3FNA  rationals are closed under division as long as the division is not by $0$. and you know $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$