# √2+√3 is irrational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I’m trying to prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

I have already proved that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. Should I use a similar approach as below or is there a different way?

Proof: $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational 
Assume $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is rational so $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=p/q$ where $p$ and $z$ are integers, $q\neq 0$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$
$r^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$ 
$r^2-5=2\sqrt{6}$ then I squared both sides…
$r^4-10r^2+25=24$ 
$r^4-10r^2+1=0$

$r=p/q$ so $p^4/q^4-10p^2/q^2+1=0$ 
 then I got a common denominator 
$p^4-10p^2q^2+q^4=0$
$p^4=10p^2q^2-q^4$

I found that $q=1$ or $-1$ and then I plugged it back into $r^4-10r^2+1=0$ and found that it can’t $=-1$ so there is a contradiction.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440453/sum-of-irrational-numbers-a-basic-algebra-problem

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by the proof that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt p_1, \sqrt p_2,\cdots, \sqrt p_n)$ is  degree $2^n$ over $\mathbb Q$, where $p_1$, etc. are distinct primes. The proof is by induction, using the same method of proof as for two primes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a shorter proof: if $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p\in\mathbb  Z$ and $q\in\mathbb N$, $q\neq 0$, then $5+\sqrt{6}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$. So, $\sqrt{6}=\frac{p^2-5q^2}{q^2}$ is rational, which is known to be false.

For $\sqrt{n}$, with $n\in\mathbb N$, you have the following alternative:

1) $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer (it happens when $n$ is a perfect square)

2) $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try proving something more general in nature, e.g. that the set
$\{1,\sqrt{p_1},\ldots,\sqrt{p_k}\}$, where $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are different primes is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. This should give you enough clues on how to approach your problem.