# An infinite extension of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory

Let $S=\{\sqrt p \in \mathbb R | p $ is a primer number$\}$.

How can I show that $\mathbb Q(S)|\mathbb Q$ is an infinite field extension?

Answer (score 0):

It follows directly from the infinity of primes and the fact that $\left[\mathbb Q[\sqrt p_1,\dots,\sqrt p_n]:\mathbb Q\right]=2^n$ for $p_1,\dots,p_n$ distinct prime numbers. This last fact is the theme of [question 113689](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f).