# A field extension problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $p_1,\dots,p_n$ be $n$ distinct prime numbers. Let $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})$ and let $q_1,\dots,q_r$ be distinct primes none of which appear in the list $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Then prove $\sqrt{q_1\cdots q_r}\notin F$.

I think this can be done by using induction on $n$, but got stuck in final step of induction. I mean how can I use induction hypothesis to prove it for $n+1$? Or is there any other way around ? Any hint?

Comment: I warmly recommend [Bill Dubuque's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/113701/11619) as well as that thread in its entirety. The claim follows from that general result (applied to the list of primes consisting of all the $p_i$:s and $q_j$:s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is: for any sequence $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ of distinct primes and for any nonempty list $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_r$ of primes not belonging to the sequence, $\sqrt{q_1\cdots q_r}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})$.

The base case, $n=0$, is obvious. Now suppose the result true for $n$ and that $t=\sqrt{q_1\cdots q_r}\in F_{n+1}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_{n+1}})$.

Let $F_n=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_{n}})$. Then $t=\alpha+\beta\sqrt{p_{n+1}}$, where $\alpha,\beta\in F_n$. Squaring gives
$$
q_1\cdots q_r=\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta\sqrt{p_{n+1}}+\beta^2p_{n+1}
$$
Since, by the induction hypothesis, $t\notin F_n$, we have $\beta\ne0$. If $\alpha=0$, we get
$$
\sqrt{q_1\cdots q_rp_{n+1}}=\beta p_{n+1}\in F_n
$$
which again goes against the induction hypothesis. Therefore $\alpha\ne0$, hence
$$
\sqrt{p_{n+1}}=\dfrac{q_1\dotsm q_r-\alpha^2-\beta^2p_{n+1}}{2\alpha\beta}\in F_n
$$
which contradicts the induction hypothesis.

Comment: This is another example which shows that a stronger claim can be proved by induction, while a weakest one it does not. I am refering to the claim $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}\notin F_n$ in your notation. This is the usual problem one encounters when study this kind of field extensions. If one tries to prove it by induction then will fail.