# Field Extension Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to show that |$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a,\sqrt b)|=4$  with a, b and ab not being squares

Is it enough to say that,

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a,\sqrt b)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a)(\sqrt b)$= {p+q$\sqrt b | p,q \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$}= {$p+q\sqrt a +r \sqrt b +s \sqrt ab$} which is clearly spanned by $1,\sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt ab$

Comment: You have to show $1$, $\sqrt a$, $\sqrt b$, $\sqrt{ab}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, which is true, but not entirely trivial.

Comment: [Take a peek at Bill Dubuque's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113701/11619). Variants and special cases have been handled on other occastions also.

Comment: Assume that $\sqrt{a} =c+d \sqrt{b}$ for some rationals $c,d$ and show a contradiction. This will show $x^2-a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{b})$