# Finding all the intermediate subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I have the following exercise :

Let $p_1,...,p_n$ be distinct primes.Consider $L= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_n})$.

Find all the intermediate subfields $K$ such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$

I have already proved that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]= 2^n$

I know that if $K$ is an intermediate subfield such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] =2$ then $[L:K] = 2^{n-1}$.

I also know that  $\sqrt{p_i}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_{i-1}})$ so :

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_{i-1}},\sqrt{p_i}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},...,\sqrt{p_{i-1}})]=2 $.

But I am not seeing how to find the ones that have degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Each subgroup $H \subseteq G$ corresponds to an intermediate field $F$, and if $\vert H \vert=2$, then $[F: \Bbb Q]=2$.  But for any element $1 \neq g \in G$, the set $\{ 1, g \} = H$ is a subgroup of $G$.  That tells you how many intermediate subfields you need to find.

Comment: I prove this result by induction on $n$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1697694/11619). I'm afraid you may find it a bit sketchy. Do observe that I needed the induction hypotheses of part c) to prove the induction step of part b). In that same thread Bill Dubuque gives a proof of part b) that does not need Galois theory for the induction step.