# Prove that $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7})$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I want to find a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I try with $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$.

Let $X = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ we get

$$ X^4 - 20X^2 + 16 = 0 $$

We can prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$ since $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ are the roots of $X^4 - 10X^2 + 21$ and it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the Eisenstein criterion with $p = 3$.

Let $P(X) = X^4 - 20X^2 + 16$. Since $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ is a root of $P$ then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}) : \mathbb{Q}] \leq 4$.
If we prove that $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the degree is equal to 4. But the Eisenstein criterion does not seem to work...

So, I try another thing. Let $\alpha = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$, we get $\alpha^2  = 10 + 2 \sqrt{21}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(10 + 2 \sqrt{21}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7})$. Now

$$ [\mathbb{Q}(10 + 2 \sqrt{21}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2 \Rightarrow 2 \mid [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}) : \mathbb{Q} ] $$

The degree must be 1, 2 or 4.

But  $\mathbb{Q}(10 + 2 \sqrt{21}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7})$ and $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}) : \mathbb{Q}(10 + 2 \sqrt{21}) ] > 1$ then the degree must be 2 or 4. I don't know how to conclude with the formula

$$ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}) : \mathbb{Q} ] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7})  :\mathbb{Q}(10 + 2 \sqrt{21}) ] [\mathbb{Q}(10 + 2 \sqrt{21}) : \mathbb{Q}]  $$

Thank you. I think I did a mistake somewhere.

Comment: For an alternative approach, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3922059/589

Comment: With this approach, since $[ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3},\sqrt{7} ) : \mathbb{Q} ] = 4$ then there are 4 elements in the basis gave by : $\left\{ 1 , \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{7}, \sqrt{21} \right\}$.
Let $\gamma = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ then $\gamma^2 = 10 + 2\sqrt{21}$, $\gamma^3 = 24 \sqrt{3} + 16 \sqrt{7}$. We get : 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ \gamma \\ \gamma^2 \\ \gamma^3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
10 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 24 & 16 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ \sqrt{3}\\ \sqrt{7} \\ \sqrt{21} \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: then $\left\{ 1, \gamma, \gamma^2 , \gamma^3 \right\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7} )$. Since this is a basis with 4 elements then $[ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7} ) : \mathbb{Q} ] = 4$. But, $[ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} , \sqrt{7} ) : \mathbb{Q} ] = 4$ then $$ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7} ) = \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{3} , \sqrt{7} )$$
as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. i.e it is the same extension and therefore, $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ is a primitive element. It is correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cubing $\alpha=\sqrt 3+\sqrt 7$, you obtain the linear system
\begin{cases}
\alpha=\sqrt 3+\sqrt 7, \\[1ex]
\alpha^3=24\sqrt 3+16\sqrt7,
\end{cases}
from which can easily deduce $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 7$ as a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $\alpha^3$.

Comment: Should $z$ be $7$ (with no $=7$) and $16\sqrt{16}$ be $16\sqrt{7}?$

Comment: @ChrisLeary: Yes. I combined a copy-paste accident and a typo. 'Tis fixed. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: It is simpler to consider $4/\alpha=\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{3}$ and then deduce that $\sqrt{3},\sqrt{7}$ both lie in $\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: A bit simpler, you're right. My first reflex is actually to show $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 7$ belong to $\mathbf Q[\alpha]$ (which is the same set, but thinking in terms of polynomials)..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your background in Galois theory, but essentially, this theory was conceived to replace tedious (and most of the time blind) polynomial calculations by natural conceptual manipulations of groups. Here we deal with quadratic and biquadratic fields. General quadratic fields are of the form $\mathbf Q(\sqrt a)$, with $a \in \mathbf Q^*, \notin \mathbf {Q^*}^2$, and it is straightforward to show that to quadratic fields $\mathbf Q(\sqrt a),\mathbf Q(\sqrt b)$ are equal iff $ab \in \mathbf {Q^*}^2$. It follows that, if $ab \notin \mathbf {Q^*}^2$, then the extension  $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt a,\sqrt b)$, which is the compositum of two distinct quadratic fields, is actually biquadratic, i.e. galois with group $G\cong C_2 \times C_2$. Obviously $G$ contains exactly three subgroups of order two, isomorphic to $C_2$. Then the first fundamental theorem of Galois theory  gives us all the subfields of $K$, which are $\mathbf Q, K$ and  three quadratic subfields, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt a),\mathbf Q(\sqrt b),\mathbf Q(\sqrt ab)$ exactly. It follows that the subfield $\mathbf Q(\sqrt a +\sqrt b)$ must coincide with $K$.

Of course we can apply this to $a=3, b=7$, but the galois approach gives much more. For instance it answers one recurrent question in this thread, which is the determination of all the subextensions of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt p_1),...,(\sqrt p_n)$, where the $p_i$ are $n$ distinct primes, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3444776/300700.