# Find the integers of degree 4 extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

So, I have been trying to solve the following problem: find the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}).$

Of course, the answer for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is clear as is for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}),$ you just look for the residue modulo $4$ and you get the answer.

However, then I got stuck because I don't know how to derive an analogous criterion for quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}).$ Can anyone suggest an approach? Thank you!

Comment: In Marcus book on number fields, the ring of integers in all biquadratic number fields is computed. Here $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt{7})$. On this site, several posts are actually related or even a duplicate. Start with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/integers-in-biquadratic-extensions). Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3943278/prove-that-sqrt3-sqrt7-is-a-primitive-element-of-mathbbq-sqrt3), why we have a biquadratic number field here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the ring of integers of a biquadratc number field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299710/on-the-ring-of-integers-of-biquadratic-number-fields).