# Showing that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, solution-verification

Let $p$ and $q$ be different prime numbers.

How to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$?

I did it this way:

$\textbf{Edit: (Is there something to improve?)}$

Proof:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})(\sqrt{q})$, because the first one is the smallest field that contains $\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, and the second one is the smallest field that contains $\sqrt{q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}$).

It's $\sqrt{q} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$, since if we suppose that we had $\sqrt{q}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ and since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ is quadratic over $\Bbb Q$ that would mean that $\sqrt{q}=a+b\sqrt{p}$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Taking squares and isolating $\sqrt{p}$:

$\sqrt{p}=\frac{q-a^2-b^2p}{2ab}\in\Bbb Q$, which is impossible.

So $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt q):\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)]=2$, since $x^2-q$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$.

The same for $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}):\mathbb{Q}]$, since $x^2-p$ is symmetric.

$\Rightarrow [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}):\mathbb{Q}]= 2 \cdot 2 =4$.

Is there something I can improve?

Comment: Compare it with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f?rq=1). You need to verify each step more clearly (see Surb's answer and Hagen's comment).

Comment: $p\ne q$ *alone* is not enough of an argument and would not work with $p=2$, $q=8$, say.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})(\sqrt{q})$ because the first one is the smallest field that contains $\sqrt{p}$, $\sqrt{q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$, and the second one is the smallest field that contains $\sqrt{q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$.

Comment: I edited my proof. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we had $\sqrt{q}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})$. Since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ is quadratic over $\Bbb Q$ that would mean that
$$
\sqrt{q}=a+b\sqrt{p}\qquad\text{for some $a$, $b\in\Bbb Q$.}
$$
Taking squares and isolating $\sqrt{p}$ :
$$
\sqrt{p}=\frac{q-a^2-b^2p}{2ab}\in\Bbb Q
$$
which is impossible.

(In fact one would have to discuss separately the case $ab=0$, but this can be dealt with very easily)

Thus
$$
\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})
$$
is a tower of quadratic extensions and one concludes by multiplicativity of the degree.

Comment: I changed the way I tried to prove it. Is it correct now or is there something wrong?

Comment: Downvoters should care to explain

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt q):\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)]=2.$$

**Hint**

$X^2-q$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{q}$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)$.