# Elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose I have  a field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. And as I know that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}: a,b\in \Bbb{Q}\}$ as a vector space basis would be $\{a,b\}$. I wanna know that how would elements be in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$? How to generalize the elements in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})$? where each $p_i$ is prime number.

Comment: "as a vector space basis would be {a,b}" -- This is unclear, as certainly $a,b$ isn't a basis (it's not even defined in the present scope).  Did you mean the coordinates would be $(a,b)$ with respect to the ordered basis $(1,\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: A typical element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ is $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6$ for $a,\ldots,d\in\Bbb Q$ etc.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ohh sorry! basis would be $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as a vector space.

Comment: See [this old thread for many approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619).

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}] = $ image of the map $\Bbb{Q}[x,y] \to \Bbb{R}$ induced by $x \mapsto \sqrt{2}$, $y \mapsto \sqrt{3}$.

Therefore $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is the set of all polynomials expressions in $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. Consider a typical monomial $\sqrt{2}^i \sqrt{3}^j$. Conclude that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is the set of all linear combinations of $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{6}$.