# The Galois group $Gal(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p_1}, \dots , \sqrt{p_n}] | \mathbb{Q})$, $p_1, \dots , p_n$ prime integers, has $2^n-1$ subgroups of index $2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Let $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p_1}, \dots , \sqrt{p_n}]$, with $p_1, \dots, p_n$ distinct prime integers. Show that the group of Galois of the extension $G = Gal(\mathbb{E} | \mathbb{Q})$ has at least $2^n - 1$ subgroups of index $2$.

The extension $\mathbb{E} | \mathbb{Q}$ is Galois of degree $2^n$ which is equal to the order of $G$. I can see, for any $i = 1, \dots , n$, $Gal(\mathbb{E} | \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p_i}])$ being a subgroup of order $2^{n-1}$ of $G$, thus of index $2$ for Lagrange. However it's far away from the $2^n-1$ claimed in the text. Any hint about it?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1 p_2})$ etc etc etc

Comment: The Galois group is an elementary abelian group of order $2^n$. So the claim follows, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f), or similar ones.

Comment: Elaborating on @ancientmathematician's comment, Pick a nonempty subset $I=\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and consider $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{p_{i_1}\cdots p_{i_k}}]$.

Comment: I gave one argument of exactly this claim in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1697694/11619) to the question Dietrich linked to. Is there something specific you want to ask about the argument? There I used the "inner product" on a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_2$ to tally the subgroups of index two. I'm sure there are other ways of seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

The Set of subgroups of index $2$ is in bijection with the set of degree-2 extensions $L/\Bbb Q$ such that $\Bbb Q \subset L \subset \Bbb Q[\sqrt p_1, \dots, \sqrt p_n]$. Any (non-empty) choice of a subset $I \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$ yields such a degree 2 extension via $L = \Bbb Q[\sqrt \pi]$, where $\pi = \prod_{i \in I} p_i$.
On the other hand, given such an extension $L$, let $D$ be the discriminant of $L/\Bbb Q$. Now we can reconstruct $\pi$ via
$$
\pi = \begin{cases} \prod_{p \mid D} p \quad & \text{if } 4 \nmid D \\ 
\prod_{4p \mid D} p \quad & \text{if } 4 \mid D.\end{cases}
$$
By theory of quadratic number fields we find $L = \Bbb Q[\sqrt \pi]$, and as $L \subset \Bbb Q[\sqrt p_1, \dots, \sqrt p_n]$ we find that $\pi$ only has prime divisors among the $p_i$ (hence is of the form
$\pi = \prod_{i \in I} p_i$ for some subset $I$).