# Formula for the minimal polynomial of sum of the roots of the integers

Tags: polynomials, summation, minimal-polynomials

Let us define $$h_N=\sum_{k=1}^N \sqrt k=\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt{N},$$ where $N$ is a positive integer. Is there a closed formula for the minimal polynomial for $h_N$?

I have tried to generate minimal polynomials for each $N$ up to 4 but I do not see any clear pattern yet.

Minimal polynomials for each $N$ so far:

1. $x-1$
2. $x^2-2x-1$
3. $x^4 - 4 x^3 - 4 x^2 + 16 x - 8$
4. $x^4 - 12 x^3 + 44 x^2 - 48 x - 8$
5. $x^8 - 24 x^7 + 212 x^6 - 792 x^5 + 622 x^4 + 3768 x^3 - 10140 x^2 + 8568 x - 2151$ (per comments)

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Wish the mods had explained why all but one previous comments were deleted - not just moved to chat, but deleted altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encouraged by the comment of [Jean Marie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie), i will slightly enlarge my comment and post it so as an answer. Let us fix a natural number $N$, and after excluding the trivial case $N=1$ we may and do assume that $N\ge 2$. Let $P$ be the list of primes less or equal $N$. Then the given number
$$\xi=\sum_{1\le k\le N}\sqrt k$$
lives in the field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt p\ :\ p\in P)$. This field is realized naturally as a tower of fields, involving extensions of degree two, at each step we adjoin the square root of a prime in $P$. For instance, using the natural order of $P$ to adjoin,
$$
\Bbb Q\to
\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)\to
\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)\to\dots\to
\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3, \dots,\sqrt{\max P})=K\ .
$$
Then the Galois group of the Galois extension $K$ of $\Bbb Q$ splits as a product of $|P|$ copies of groups with two elements, each generated by a Galois morphism of the shape $\sqrt p\to-\sqrt p$. So the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ is
$$
f_N(X)=\prod_{e:P\to\{-1, 1\}}\left(\ X - \left(\sum_{1\le k\le N} \bar e(k)\sqrt k\right)\ \right)\ .
$$
Here, $\bar e$ is the unique multiplicative extension of $e$, which is defined only on $P$, to all natural numbers $k$ from $1$ to $N$. To get $\bar e(k)$ we factor $k$ over the integers, in the factorization there are only primes from $P$, taken to some powers, and we define $\bar e(k)$ to be the sign obtained from the factorization by replacing each prime $p$ by the sign $e(p)$. For instance, if the following sample primes are in $P$, $\bar e(4)
=\bar e(2^2)=e(2)^2=1$, and it does not depend on $e$, same argument gives $e(k^2)=1$, $\bar e(6)=\bar e(2\cdot 3):=e(2)\cdot e(3)$, $\bar e(12)=\bar e(2^2\cdot 3):=e(2)^2\cdot e(3)=e(3)$, and so on.

The formula is not really useful, but it shows the the degree of $f_N$ is $2^{|P|}$. For instance, if $N=6$, then there $P=\{2,3,5\}$, and we expect the degree $2^{|P|}=2^3=8$ for this minimal polynomial. Indeed, asking for this polynomial in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org)...

```
sage: xi = (sum([sqrt(k) for k in [1..6]])).minpoly()
sage: xi
x^8 - 24*x^7 + 188*x^6 - 456*x^5 - 722*x^4 + 3768*x^3 - 468*x^2 - 6552*x + 441
```

we get a polynomial of degree eight. For $N=7$ there is a jump, the degree is $2^4=16$, and this is so for $N=7,8,9,10$, the next jump in degree being for $N=11$, with degree $2^5=32$.

Explicitly, the above polynomial $f_6$ was obtained as a product of the following linear factors:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&X - (1 +\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3 + 2 +\sqrt 5 +\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(+1,+1,+1)\ ,\\
&X - (1 +\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3 + 2 -\sqrt 5 +\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(+1,+1,-1)\ ,\\[2mm]
&X - (1 +\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3 + 2 +\sqrt 5 -\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(+1,-1,+1)\ ,\\
&X - (1 +\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3 + 2 -\sqrt 5 -\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(+1,-1,-1)\ ,\\[4mm]
&X - (1 -\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3 + 2 +\sqrt 5 -\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(-1,+1,+1)\ ,\\
&X - (1 -\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3 + 2 -\sqrt 5 -\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(-1,+1,-1)\ ,\\[2mm]
&X - (1 -\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3 + 2 +\sqrt 5 +\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(-1,-1,+1)\ ,\\
&X - (1 -\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3 + 2 -\sqrt 5 +\sqrt 6)\ ,& e=(-1,-1,-1)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Well, sage may have done something else, so let us check explicitly the result obtained by multiplying these linear factors:

```
sage: var('X');
sage: prod([ X - (1 + e2*sqrt(2) + e3*sqrt(3) + 2 + e5*sqrt(5) + e2*e3*sqrt(6))
....:        for (e2, e3, e5) in cartesian_product([[-1, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, 1]]) ]) \
....:     .expand().canonicalize_radical()
X^8 - 24*X^7 + 188*X^6 - 456*X^5 - 722*X^4 + 3768*X^3 - 468*X^2 - 6552*X + 441
sage:
```

Et voilà!

Comment: On a linux box sagemath is in most distributions already in the main repository, one click will install. (On other systems... i don't know, but it should doable in short time.) Questions in case of issues with installations, with packages may be directed to https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/ - there are also other platforms. Structural problems with the main accent on the mathematical part are often posted here, there is a sage-tag for them. Problems with a strategy of coding / implementing a specific problem rather on the asksage platform. Note that you have quick access to the code.

Answer (score 3):

(*Previously posted as a comment, that was deleted by the mods alongside several others for no good reason. Leaving it as an answer now, hopefully useful to the OP and/or future readers.*)

To start with the simplest example, finding a rational polynomial with $x = 1 + \sqrt{2}$ as a root is equivalent to eliminating $a$ between the polynomial equations $x = 1 + a, a^2 = 2$. This can be done with [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Solutions_of_a_system_of_algebraic_equations), for example using WA: $\;f(h_2) =$ [`GroebnerBasis[{x-1-a,a^2-2},{x},{a}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bx-1-a%2Ca%5E2-2%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%2C%7Ba%7D%5D) $= x^2 - 2 x - 1\,$, where $f(h)$ is the polynomial in the Gröbner basis having $h$ a root. Similarly:

- $f(h_5) =$ [`GroebnerBasis[{x-1-a-b-2-c,a^2-2,b^2-3,c^2-5},{x},{a,b,c}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bx-1-a-b-2-c%2Ca%5E2-2%2Cb%5E2-3%2Cc%5E2-5%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%5D) 
  $= x^8 - 24 x^7 + 212 x^6 - 792 x^5 + 622 x^4 + 3768 x^3 - 10140 x^2 + 8568 x - 2151$
- $f(h_6) =$ [`GroebnerBasis[{x-1-a-b-2-c-ab,a^2-2,b^2-3,c^2-5},{x},{a,b,c}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bx-1-a-b-2-c-ab%2Ca%5E2-2%2Cb%5E2-3%2Cc%5E2-5%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%5D) 
  $= x^8 - 24 x^7 + 188 x^6 - 456 x^5 - 722 x^4 + 3768 x^3 - 468 x^2 - 6552 x + 441$
- $f(h_7) =$ [`GroebnerBasis[{x-1-a-b-2-c-ab-d,a^2-2,b^2-3,c^2-5,d^2-7},{x},{a,b,cd}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bx-1-a-b-2-c-ab-d%2Ca%5E2-2%2Cb%5E2-3%2Cc%5E2-5%2Cd%5E2-7%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D%5D) 
  $= x^{16} - 48 x^{15} + 896 x^{14} - 7584 x^{13} + 15776 x^{12} + 213120 x^{11} - 1623552 x^{10} + 2379264 x^9 + 16915712 x^8 - 77223936 x^7 + 67215360 x^6 + 254509056 x^5 - 721125376 x^4 + 708771840 x^3 - 260571136 x^2 + 12845056$

These polynomials each have the respective sum of radicals as a root, though the above alone does not prove that they are in fact the minimal polynomials.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Not a formal proof, but an outline below of why, provided some preparatory steps are taken, $f(h_N)$ is indeed the minimal polynomial of degree $2^{\pi(N)}$ of $h_N$ (where $\pi(N)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)).

- The square root of every $n \le N$ can be written as $\sqrt{n} = a_n \sqrt{b_n}$ where $a_n$ is an integer and $b_n$ is the square-free [radical of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer),  which is a product of distinct primes $\le n$. For example, $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and $\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{3}\,$. Therefore, $h_N$ can be written as a polynomial combination of square roots of primes $\sqrt{p_k}\;\big|_{\,k \le\pi(N)}$. For example, $h_6=1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\underbrace{2}_{=\sqrt{4}}+\sqrt{5}+\underbrace{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{3}}_{=\sqrt{6}}\,$.
- The degree in $x$ of $f(h_N)$ in the Gröbner basis of $x - h_N, x_k^2 - p_k\;\big|_{\,k \le\pi(n)}$ where $x_k=\sqrt{p_k}$ is no larger than $2^{\pi(N)}$, because a polynomial of degree $2^{\pi(N)}$ in $x$ can be obtained via repeated use of [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) and $f(h_N)$ cannot have a higher degree than that one.
- The minimal polynomial of $h_N$ has in fact degree $2^{\pi(N)}$, see for example [Proving that $\left(\mathbb Q[\sqrt p_1,\dots,\sqrt p_n]:\mathbb Q\right)=2^n$ for distinct primes $p_i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f), so $f(h_N)$ is actually the minimal polynomial of $h_N\,$.