# $E = \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_n})$. Show that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Hey I want to check if my solutions for this exercise are right.

Let $E = \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_n})$ with $n$ pairwise different prime numbers $p_1, . . . , p_n$. Show that $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$.

Every minimal polynomial is normal and separable so we  have that $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois.

What I thought is to use this Theorem that we have done in class:

Let $p_1 < p_2 < p_3 < p_4 < . . .$ the sequence of prime numbers. For every $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ we have $[\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_n}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^n$

So I have that $[E/\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_n}) : \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-1}})]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-1}}) : \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-2}})]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}) : \mathbb{Q}]=2^n$

Where every $[\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-1}}) : \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-2}})]=2$ and therefore every $|Gal(\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-1}}) / \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-2}}))|=2$ and $\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

we have $Gal(E/K)= Gal([\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_n})/ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}, . . . , \sqrt{p_{n-1}})])\cdot...\cdot Gal(\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{p_1}) / \mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$

Am I right or have I done any mistake?

Comment: Compare with the answers in [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619). Some are only concerned with proving the dimension. Some also look at the Galois group. With basic facts about Galois extensions in place getting the group structure is rather straight forward because we have a good idea where an automorphism must send each of the square roots, and we also know how many automorphisms there are altogether.