# Degree of extension of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a_1},\cdots,\sqrt{a_n})$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Assume $a_1,\cdots,a_n \in \mathbb N_+$, none of which is perfect square and each pair of them is coprime. Proof that
> $$
> [\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a_1},\cdots,\sqrt{a_n}): \mathbb Q]=2^n
> $$

I have tried a lot but I don't have any progress. Can someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Another duplicate is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113689/proving-that-left-mathbb-q-sqrt-p-1-dots-sqrt-p-n-mathbb-q-right-2n-f?noredirect=1&lq=1), where the proof is not only for prime numbers.