# Prove $\, a,b,c, \sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c} \in\mathbb Q \implies \sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c} \in\mathbb Q $ and generalization to $n$ summands.

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

Assume that $a，b，c, \sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c} \in\mathbb Q$ are rational，prove $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c}  \in\mathbb Q$,are rational.

I know that can be proved, would like to know that there is no easier way

[image]

$\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt c = p \in \mathbb Q$,
$\sqrt a + \sqrt b  = p- \sqrt c$,
$a+b+2\sqrt a \sqrt b = p^2+c-2p\sqrt c$,
$2\sqrt a\sqrt b=p^2+c-a-b-2p\sqrt c$,
$4ab=(p^2+c-a-b)+4p^2c-4p(p^2+c-a-b)\sqrt c$,
$\sqrt c=\frac{(p^2+c-a-b)+4p^c-4ab}{4p(p^2+c-a-b)}\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Looks good, the only thing that needs to be done is to mqke sure we are not dividing by $0$.

Comment: Exactly; how do you know $p^2+c-a-b\ne0$? Also, the line that starts $4ab=$ should have $(p^2+c-a-b)^2$ in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3073947/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217811/242) for an introduction to the proof. They are explicitly worked special cases].

As you surmise, induction works, employing our prior [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136600/242) (case $\rm\,n = 2\,\!).\,$ Put $\rm\,K = \mathbb Q\,$ in

**Theorem** $\rm\ \sqrt{c_1}+\cdots+\!\sqrt{c_{n}} = k\in K\ \Rightarrow \sqrt{c_i}\in K\,$ for all $\,\!\rm i,\,$ if $\rm\, 0 < c_i\in K\:\!$  an ordered field.

**Proof** $\, $ By induction on $\:\!\rm n.\,$ Clear if $\rm\,n=1.\,$ It is true for $\rm\,n=2\,$ by said Lemma.  Suppose  $\rm\, n>2.$ Below  we prove $\rm\color{#0af}{one}$ of the square-roots is in $\rm K\:\!$. Hence the sum of all of the others is also in $\rm K,\,$ thus, by induction, all of the others are also in $\rm K,\,$ finishing the proof.

Note that $\rm\,\sqrt{c_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{c_{n-1}}\, =\, k\! -\! \sqrt{c_n}\in K(\sqrt{c_n})\,$ so all $\,\rm\sqrt{c_j}\in K(\sqrt{c_n})\,$ by induction.

Therefore $\rm\, \sqrt{c_j} =\, a_j + b_j\sqrt{c_n}\,$ for some $\rm\,a_j,\,\!b_j\in K,\,$ for $\rm\,j=1,\ldots,n\!-\!1$.

$\rm \color{#0a0}{Some\,\ {b_j < 0}}\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\ a_j = \sqrt{c_j}-b_j\sqrt{c_n} = \sqrt{c_j}+\!\sqrt{b_j^2 c_n}\in K\,\Rightarrow \color{#0af}{\sqrt{c_j}}\in K\,$ by Lemma $\rm(n\!=\!2).$

Else $\,\rm \color{#90f}{all\ b_j \ge 0},\,$ so $\rm\,  b := b_1\!+\cdots+b_{n-1} \ge 0.\,$ Let $\rm\, a := a_1\!+\cdots+a_{n-1}\ $  so
$$\rm \sqrt{c_1}+\cdots+\!\sqrt{c_{n}}\, =\, a+(b\!+\!1)\,\sqrt{c_n} = k\in K\,\Rightarrow\,\!\color{#0af}{\sqrt{c_n}}= {\small \frac{\!k\!-\!a}{\color{#c00}{b\!+\!1}}}\in K\quad  $$

So in $\rm\color{#0a0}{every}\ \color{#90f}{case}\ \color{#0af}{one}$ of the square-roots lies in $\rm K\,$ (notice that $\rm\,b\ge0\,\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{b\!+\!1}\ne 0).\,$ $\  \bf\small QED$

**Remark** $ $ The *positivity* of the  summands is crucial (else e.g. $\,-\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\in \mathbb Q\,$ but $\rm\,\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb Q).\,$ More generally see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242) on the linear independence of square-roots (Besicovic's theorem).

Comment: The current solution, I do not quite understand.
I would like to see your simple proof of, thank you

Comment: @pxc417 I added further details - see above.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not easier, but quite elegant :

Suppose that $a,b,c$ are all non zero. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c})$ and $n = [K: \mathbb{Q}]$. Then since $Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{a}) = Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})/\mathbb{Q}} \circ Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})} (\sqrt{a})$, we have
$$ Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{a}) = \begin{cases} 0,& \text{if } \sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Q} \\ n\sqrt{a}, &\text{if } \sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}, \end{cases}$$
and same for $\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$.

By hypothesis $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} +\sqrt{c} \in \mathbb{Q}$, so
$$ Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{a}) + Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{b}) + Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{c}) = n\sqrt{a} + n \sqrt{b} + n \sqrt{c}.$$
It is easy to conclude that $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c} \in \mathbb{Q}$.