# Show that $ a，b, \sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b} \in\mathbb Q \implies \sqrt{a},\sqrt{b} \in\mathbb Q $

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136556/show-that-abc-sqrta-sqrtb-sqrtc-in-mathbb-q-implies-sqrta), I was wondering if there is a simple logical argument to

Show that $ a,b, \sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b} \in\mathbb Q  \implies  \sqrt{a},\sqrt{b} \in\mathbb Q $

Note that the original link is using a computational method, where as I am looking for a simple logical argument.

I tried (unjutifiably) to argue that if some of two square roots is rational then each one is rational, this is a different than the (incorrect) argument that if sum of two algebraic numbers is rational then each one is rational ( counter example $a=1-\sqrt{2},b= 1+\sqrt{2} $)

Comment: Being, or not being, in the rationals is a computational concept, so the search for a non-computational method is doomed.

Comment: If the term "logical argument" is meant as "a formal proof in the language of fields" then I apologize for the retag. If it meant something else, then I am not sorry - it has nothing to do with [logic].

Comment: @Asaf : You are completly correct, what I meant was something similar to simple logical reasoning like "sum of rational and irrational is irrational" type of statement. Thank you for your courtesy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I consider Bill's answer to be sufficiently noncomputational, maybe my usage of "noncomputational" is not correct in this context.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530778 and the generalization in the accepted answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951609

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}$ be rational if neither $n,m$ are perfect squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\: = \dfrac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}\ $ so $\rm\ \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb Q\:\Rightarrow\:\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb Q\:\Rightarrow\:$ sum/2  $\rm =  \sqrt{a}\in \mathbb Q$

**Remark** $ $ This [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136655/242) to a positive sum of any number of square roots over an *ordered* field.

Comment: It's more a complete solution than a hint :)

Comment: The case $a=b=0$ has to be done separately (otherwise we cannot write down the fraction here).

Comment: @Martin Yes, of course (generally hints leave trivial degenerate cases for the reader).

Answer (score 6):

$$\sqrt a + \sqrt b \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \sqrt a + \sqrt b = \dfrac{p}{q}$$

$$\sqrt a = \dfrac{p}{q} - \sqrt b$$
$$a = \dfrac{p^2}{q^2} - 2 \cdot \dfrac{p}{q} \sqrt b + b$$

So if $a,b$ are rational, this forces their square roots to be also.

Comment: Note: This is arguably "computational". I just now checked out the link in the OP (a rare occurrence...)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a+b=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2-2\sqrt{ab}$ and since both a+b and $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ are rational, we may claim that $\sqrt{ab}$ is also rational. These remind us of the quadratic: $(x-\sqrt{a})(x-\sqrt{b})=x^2-2x(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})+\sqrt{ab}$ Solving for x gives us $x=\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+-\sqrt{a+b-2\sqrt{ab}}}{2}$ which implies that if $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ is rational, then so are $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$. Since $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ and both $a-b$ and $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ are rational, we may conclude that both $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are rational.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the part about not being computational. Also, this just boils down to Bill Dubuque's proof.

Comment: Me neither! Let's hope you avoid the serial downvoters :)

Comment: @TheChaz The downvote is a bit puzzling. I'd ask for an explanation.

Comment: @Bill: I know you would! Honestly, I'll probably just chalk it up to the same serial downvoter(s) that have been targeting me of late. It's not a big deal, and I'm kinda surprised that it doesn't happen *more often*, considering my abrasive tendencies...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. Now suppose $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=p/q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q>0$. Then
$$q(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=p\implies q^2(a+b+2\sqrt{ab})=p^2$$
$$\implies 4q^4ab=(p^2-q^2(a+b))^2$$

Hence we have $q|p^4$. But $\gcd(p,q)=1\implies\gcd(p^4,q)=1$. Now since $q$ is a divisor of $p^4$, $q\leq 1$, therefore $q=1$.
Now we have
$$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=p\implies a=(p-\sqrt{b})^2$$
$$2p\sqrt{b}=p^2+b-a$$
Now this implies that $\sqrt{b}$ is rational if $p\neq0$, hence $p=0$ and $0=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}>0$, thus this is a contradiction.
$$\square$$