# Prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n}$ is irrational when $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, irrational-numbers

Prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n}$ is irrational $\forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have tried though contradiction but can't seem to come up with an answer

I did this where for $\frac ab$, $a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and in reduce form, and $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n = \frac ab$$
$$\frac {2+n}{\sqrt 2 - \sqrt n} = \frac ab$$
$$\frac {(2+n)(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n)}{2 + n} = \frac ab$$
$$\frac {(2+n)(a)}{(2-n)(b)}=\frac ab$$
$$\frac {2+n}{2-n}=1$$
$$2+n=2-n$$
$$2+2n=2$$
$$n=0$$
$$n \in \mathbb{N} \therefore n \not =0$$
$$\therefore  \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$$

However this seems clearly flawed as even if $n = 0$ it still would be irrational, and that it subsitiuting $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n$ for $\frac ab$ seems pretty incorrect.

More just a desperate attempt, pretty confident its not even close.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares/457384#457384

Comment: The step between 3. and 4. equation is wrong: should be $n+2$ in denominator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{n}\in\Bbb Q$.  Since the ratio of rationals is rational, $\frac{2-n}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{n}\in\Bbb Q$. Averaging, $\sqrt2\in\Bbb Q$, which contradicts a well-known result.

Comment: So basically whats happening is you are claiming that for $\frac {2-n}{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ both the numerator and denominator have to be rational, So assuming that both are rational you take $\sqrt 2 - \sqrt n \in \mathbb {Q}$, then that is only true if the average of the two radicals, which in this case is $\sqrt 2$ is rational, thus contridicting. I don't really follow why the average of the two radicals is $\sqrt 2$ though.

Comment: @Dakota Because their sum is $2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I still don't quite follow. If $n = 2$ then I understand $2\sqrt2$ but why for all n?

Comment: @Dakota Summing $\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{n}$ gives an $n$-independent result.

Comment: So we sum $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n$ and $\sqrt 2 - \sqrt n$ given $2\sqrt 2$. So is the reasoning that if $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt n$ and $\sqrt 2 - \sqrt n$ are $\in \mathbb{Q}$ then the average of them must be $\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Dakota Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator in your second line should be $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{n}) = 2 - n$.
... and then your fourth line is a tautology.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. It has been awhile so I messed that part up. Thank you.