# Proving that $(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2)/(\sqrt 2)$ is irrational

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers

Can you please help me prove this ? I can prove that $\sqrt p$, where p is prime is irrational, also that the sum $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ is irational, bud dont know how to prove that the whole fraction is irrational. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares for a general case and elegant proofs.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}=1+\sqrt{3/2}$$
The whole fraction is irrational iff $\sqrt{3/2}=\frac12\sqrt6$ is irrational iff $\sqrt6$ is irrational. The last statement you should be able to prove.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}\in\mathbb Q$ so $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\in\mathbb Q.$

Now, let $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{m}{n},$ where $m$ and $n$ are naturals such that  $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and get a contradiction.

Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $r=(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})/\sqrt{2}$. Then
$$
3=2(r-1)^2
$$
The possible positive rational roots of
$$
2x^2-4x+1
$$
are $1$ and $1/2$, neither of which is actually a root.