# Can I write the difference of a rational and a square root of a rational as a sum of a rational and a square root of a rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $x = p - \sqrt{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are rational and $q \geq 0$. Can I always find rational numbers $\tilde p, \tilde q$ such that $\tilde q \geq 0$ and
\begin{align*}
x = \tilde p + \sqrt{ \tilde q}
\end{align*}

Comment: If $\sqrt q$ is rational. Writing $p - \tilde p = \sqrt q + \sqrt {\tilde q}$ transforms your question into a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136594/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless $\sqrt{q}$ is rational.

Rewrite the equation $p - \sqrt{q} = \overline{p} + \sqrt{\overline{q}}$  as
$$ x = \sqrt{q} + \sqrt{\overline{q}} \tag 1$$
where $x = p - \overline{p}$, and square both sides:
$$ x^2 = q + 2 \sqrt{q \overline{q}} + \overline{q}^2$$

Since all other terms are rational, $\sqrt{q \overline{q}}$ must be rational.
If $r = \sqrt{q \overline{q}}$, that says $\overline{q} = r^2/q$.  Equation (1)
then becomes $$x = \sqrt{q} + r/\sqrt{q} $$
so that
$$  x \sqrt{q} = q + r $$
Now $\sqrt{q}\ge 0$ and $\sqrt{\overline{q}} \ge 0$.  Unless they are $0$, $x > 0$
and $\sqrt{q} = (q+r)/x$ is rational.

Answer (score 2):

No, except for the trivial case $\sqrt{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Hint:
$$p-\sqrt{q}=\bar{p}+\sqrt{\bar{q}}\\
\bar{q}=(p-\bar{p}-\sqrt{q})^2=(p-\bar{p})^2+q-2(p-\bar{p})\sqrt{q}$$

> This forces $p=\bar{p}$ since $\sqrt{q}$ is irrational, but then $-\sqrt{q}=+\sqrt{\bar{q}}$, a contradiction.