# Infinite Degree Algebraic Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In I. Martin Isaacs Algebra: A Graduate Course, Isaacs uses the field of algebraic numbers $$\mathbb{A}=\{\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \; | \; \alpha \; \text{algebraic over} \; \mathbb{Q}\}$$ as an example of an infinite degree algebraic field extension. I have done a cursory google search and thought about it for a little while, but I cannot come up with a less contrived example.

My question is

> What are some other examples of infinite degree algebraic field extensions?

Comment: One example which is quite natural is the field given by adjoining all roots of unity or all radicals to $\mathbb Q$. But I must say, I don't like this question: It is not that hard to give you any number of infinite algebraic field extensions (take a suitable collection of polynomials and consider the splitting field), but it seems like there is very little to be learned from such an exercise in thinking up *any* examples.

Comment: @MTurgeon $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)/\mathbb{Q}$ is not algebraic.

Comment: How are the algebraic numbers a contrived example? They are the largest algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$! Any infinite algebraic extension lies in them!

Comment: @Holdsworth88 I misread the requirements for this infinite degree extension.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337046/field-of-algebraic-numbers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another simple example is the extension obtained by adjoining all roots of unity.

Since adjoining a primitive $n$-th root of unity gives you an extension of degree $\varphi(n)$ and $\varphi(n)=n-1$ when $n$ is prime, you get algebraic numbers of arbitrarily large degree when you adjoin all roots of unity.

Comment: And, as is well-known, this is the largest *abelian* algebraic extension

Answer (score 18):

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 5, \cdots]$, obtained by adjoining the square root of the primes, is an example because if you use just $n$ primes, you get an extension of degree $2^n$.

Comment: This is far from obvious, though (see http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/ for a proof and a link to other proofs). If you want to be lazy, take $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/2}, 2^{1/4}, 2^{1/8}, ...]$.

Comment: For a proof, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-ration

Comment: So I suppose $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m_1},\sqrt{m_2},...)$, where the $m_i$ are square-free coprime integers would also be an example then.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Dear Qiaochu, While you are right that this result is not obvious, it is not *that* hard; it follows from the most basic algebraic number theory (more precisely, computations of discriminants for quadratic extensions).  Regards,

Answer (score 12):

The field of algebraic numbers *is* important, as is the field of real algebraic numbers.  There are plenty of other examples of the same nature. The field of Euclidean constructible numbers is an extension field of the rationals, of infinite degree over the rationals, that comes up "naturally."

Answer (score 3):

How about the following example: for any field $k$, consider the field extension $\cup_{n\geq 1} k(t^{2^{-n}})$ of the field $k(t)$ of rational functions. This extension is algebraic and of infinite dimension. The idea behind is quite simple. But I admit it require some work to define the extension rigorously.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{n_1,n_2,...\}$ be pairwise coprime, nonsquare positive integers. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n_1},\sqrt{n_2},...)$ is an algebraic extension of infinite degree.