# field of algebraic numbers

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Would anyone be able to give me an outline or a hint towards the proof that the field of algebraic numbers is an infinite extension of the field of rationals?
Many Thanks

Comment: If you consider the field as an vector space over $\mathbb Q$, if the vector space was finite-dimensional of dimension $n$, that would mean that every algebraic number satisfies a rational polynomial of degree $n$. So you just need to show that for any $n$ there is an irreducible rational polynomial of degree $>n$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151586/infinite-degree-algebraic-field-extensions.

Answer (score 24):

If you know [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), you might consider the algebraic numbers $\sqrt[n]{2}$, for which one has
$$
\lvert \Bbb{Q} [\sqrt[n]{2}] : \Bbb{Q} \rvert = n,
$$
since the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{2}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $x^n - 2$, as the latter is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein.

Since $n \ge 1$ is arbitrary, this shows that the degree of the field of the algebraic numbers over the rationals cannot be finite.

Comment: perfect thankyou!

Comment: @OGSK, you're welcome!

Comment: +1 About accepting it I'd say the OP can still wait a little, since perhaps some other answer(s) may come that (s)he will love better, but it is always nice to *upvote* any answer that helps even a little...

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks, you are right, I am deleting my comment.

Comment: Anyway @AndreasCaranti, I'd remind the OP *later*...many times either they don't know or they forget.