# Basis of $\mathbb R$ seen as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, set-theory, irrational-numbers, axiom-of-choice

$\mathbb R$ is clearly a $\mathbb Q$-vector space since all axioms needed to be a vector space are verified. Its basis is infinite because it would need to have all roots, $\pi$, $e$...

1. Is there any quick and "relatively easy" but solid proof that this statement is true ? I don't know how to formally write "the basis needs to contain all (actually not all but still a lot) irrationals and |$\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q$| would be bigger than some uncountable set.
2. Can we write the basis in a simple form ? What I mean is that, the basis of polynomials $\mathbb R$[t] is infinite but can be written as {$t^k$ , k $\in$ $\mathbb N$}

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  The basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ must be uncountable as a countable union of countable sets is countable.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: You can prove that a finite dimensional vector space over a countable field is countable, as there is an injection from a $d$ dimensional $F-$vector space to $F^d$ given by $a_1x_1+\ldots+a_dx_d\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_d)$ where $a_1,\ldots, a_d\in F$, $x_1,...,x_d$ are the basis vectors.

Comment: The problem here is that the proof of existence of such a basis relies on the Axiom of Choice. In other words, such a basis can not be explicitly descrbed.

Comment: Every vector space over any field has a basis. The proof of this theorem  uses the axiom of choice, and more precisely that every  set  can be well-ordered. A basis  of $\mathbf R$ over $\mathbf Q$ is called a *Hamel basis*. I don't know of any simple, explicit description.

Comment: @Bernard and even if there was a description, it would involve a structure equally complicated as the Hamel basis.

Comment: I'm asking how to show it's infinite (i thought of showing that I can find sets of linear independant vectors as big as I want) and if the basis could be written as for example {$\sqrt(x),\pi,e,sin(2)...$} maybe

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks for your answers everybody !

Comment: If $\mathbf R$ were finite-dimensional over $\mathbf Q$, it would be an algebraic extension of $\mathbf Q$ (as a field). It is known since that numbers such as $\pi$ or $\mathrm e$  are transcendental. (Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: Regarding complexity of describing a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46063/explicit-hamel-basis-of-real-numbers.  In particular, no such basis can be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$, so it has to be fairly complicated.  On the other hand, in some universes of set theory there is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that if you project that set to $\mathbb{R}^2$, take the complement of that, and then project that complement into $\mathbb{R}$, you get a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so a basis doesn't have to be *horrifically* complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By definition, the powers of $\pi$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ since $\pi$ is transcendental. Therefore, $\mathbb Q[\pi]$ is a infinite-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R$.
2. No description of a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ is known. In most if not all definitions, a *description* is a string in a language and so there are only countably many descriptions, not enough to describe an uncountable set.

Comment: For 1, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151598/589