# Linear independence in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The square roots of the primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-ration)

I would like to prove that the family $\{\sqrt{p}, p\text{ prime number} \}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb R$ where $\mathbb R$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

I know how to prove this for up to 4 elements but I would like a general proof as elementary as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Sebastian

Comment: You may be interested in http://www.thehcmr.org/issue2_1/mfp.pdf

Comment: The problem has come up on MSE. There is a detailed answer, with many additional references,  by Bill Dubuque. [Here is  a link.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-the-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of-ration)

Comment: (I hate to read "linear independance" ;-). Therefore, even though people want to close this thread, I tried to change it to "linear independence" which I was not allowed to do, since a posting with that heading already existed. For this reason I slightly changed the heading, hope this is ok for you).

Comment: Thanks for correcting my spelling (I'm not a native english speaker)!

Comment: Thanks, so it seems there is not a very elementary solution. This exercise comes from a list of exercises for beginning linear algebra and the next exercise asked the same question for $\log(p)$ (that is quite easy).

Comment: The first inductive solution in the link I gave is about as elementary as it gets (in the sense that it doesn't require much background theory), but "elementary" and "easy" are very different things.