# $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoining primes and the sum of root of those primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, adjoint-operators

I have $p$, $q$ as primes, and I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$.

I was thinking about using inclusion both ways, so what does an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$ look like? Does it mean that $\sqrt{p}$ and $\sqrt{q}$ satisfy the polynomial $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$? I am sorta stuck on what to do next, and what is the role of the primes?

Comment: you tried to prove at least one way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's clear that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$.
   We need to prove the other way.
   $$\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$$
   $$\implies \sqrt{pq} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$$
   $$\implies q\sqrt{p}+p\sqrt{q} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$$
   $$\implies \sqrt{q} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$$
   and we are done.
2. An element in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$ looks like $(a+b\sqrt p +c\sqrt q+d \sqrt pq)$.
3. The polymonial they satisfy is $(x^2-p)(x^2-q) \in \Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: why would $ \sqrt{pq} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$?

Comment: $(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^2 \in \Bbb Q (\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$

Comment: Oh yeah.... I got it!!

Comment: @viplov_jain why is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}))$ clear?

Comment: since rings are closed under addition

Comment: @viplov_jain: yeah, I figured that 5 mins after I typed the question. How do you get from $\sqrt{pq}$ to $q\sqrt{p}+p\sqrt{q}$?

Comment: multiply the two things

Answer (score 2):

One simple way: $\rm\ F = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}) \supseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})\,$ (reverse is clear),  since $\rm\,F\,$ contains not only $\, u = \sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}\, $ but also $\,v = \sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q} = (p-q)/(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}), \, $ so $\,\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q} = (u\pm v)/2 \in\rm F.\, $ **QED** $ $  For much further discussion [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674038/242)

Comment: Above i used $\ (\sqrt{p}-\!\sqrt{q})(\sqrt{p}+\!\sqrt{q}) = \sqrt{p}^2-\!\sqrt{q}^2 = p - q\ \ $ (divide it by $\ \sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})\ \ $