# Can someone explain to me this answer about subrings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

so I know how to prove that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{2}\right]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{3}\right]=\{a+b\sqrt{3}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ are subrings of $\mathbb{R}$. However, I don't understand the following proofs. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

**Question:** Give a one sentence intuitive reason why the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ cannot be isomorphic.

**Answer:** $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ are not isomorphic because $2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ but it is in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

**What I don't understand:** What does it mean by "$2$ is not a *square* in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ but it is in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$"?

And,

**Question:** Convert your intuition into a rigorous proof.

**Answer:** If $\Psi:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ then $\Psi(1)=1, so \Psi(2)=\Psi(1+1)=\Psi(1)+\Psi(1)=1+1=2$ and hence $\Psi(\sqrt{2})=x$ has the property that $x^2=\Psi(\sqrt{2})^2=\Psi((\sqrt{2})^2)=\Psi(2)=2$.

Let $x=a+b\sqrt{3}$. We deduce $(a^2+3b^2)+2ab\sqrt{3}=2$ 
$$\implies\sqrt{3}=\frac{2-a^2-3b^2}{2ab}\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ (since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational),}$$

provided $ab\ne 0$.

If $a=0$, then $x=b\sqrt{3}$ so $x^2=3b^2=2$, which is impossible.

And if $b=0$, then $x^2=a^2=2$, which is also impossible.

**What I don't understand:** what is $\Psi$? I don't understand how it gives those results for $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: "$x$ is a square" means "there is a $y$ such that $y^2 = x$".

Comment: $\Psi$ is ring homomorphism and they use properties of ring homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! OK, so I now understand why 2 is a square in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and not in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: And that also explains the second part of the question :)

Comment: See the Lemma in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/674038/242) tor a generalization of the method used in the answer.